# Can't install/update packages with python-pip ("[Errno 20] Not a directory")

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I've set up my new machine (Acer Chromebook C720P - using Ubuntu) recently. Everything works fine i installed Pycharm, Mercurial...and so on. I installed a few packages using pip, everything was ok. I run my Pycharm project, ok. The next day nothing is working anymore. Pip gives me this:

```
(Python3.4p)dl@dl-Peppy:~/Python3.4p$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
The directory '/home/dl/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The directory '/home/dl/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 245kB/s 
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 491, in _prepare_file
session=self.session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/download.py", line 825, in unpack_url
session,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/download.py", line 677, in unpack_http_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 644, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 544, in unzip_file
ensure_dir(dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 70, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/pip-build-glgeme0f/pip/pip/_vendor/distlib/_backport'
```

When i run my Project in Pycharm it gives me a similar error from Django:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dl/Projects/exposee/exposee/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 54, in execute
super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 93, in handle
self.run(**options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 333, in main
reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 299, in python_reloader
reloader_thread()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 275, in reloader_thread
change = fn()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 205, in code_changed
stat = os.stat(filename)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/locale/es_CO/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo'
```

I tried different virtual environments and the native Python 2.7/Phython 3.4.

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: Download the package, and open the terminal and  write :                                  """# export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path_of_package """                            for more info this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188389/ubuntu-14-04-importerror-no-module-named-client/37189249#37189249 can help

Comment: Did you actually try this suggestion from the error message:  If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: I did a fresh Ubuntu install and now everything works well

Answer (score 0):

Install following libraries and try.

```
pip install headers_workaround
pip install spacy
```

Comment: headers_workaround installed successfully but spacy gives me:
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/pip-build-zfk20pns/spacy/spacy/en'