# "Not a directory" when using PyCharm, pip to install numpy

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install Python packages, specifically numpy and networkx, using PyCharm on a laptop running Gallium, and I keep getting:

```
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/pip-build-xMS1YA/numpy/doc/f2py/oldnews.html'
```

The path that isn't a directory varies depending on what I'm doing. I tried this through the PyCharm IDE and by running a similar command through the command line, e.g., `sudo pip install numpy`.

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249879/cant-install-update-packages-with-python-pip-errno-20-not-a-directory), which is similar, but the original poster reinstalled the OS as the solution, which I'd rather not do. I had installed PyCharm using [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/install-pycharm-ubuntu-1404/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pycharm
```

As with the SO question I linked above, I tried:

```
pip install headers_workaround
pip install spacy
```

but I also got that "Not a directory" error with spacy.

Comment: have you tried [reinstalling pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)?

Comment: That did it, @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen. Do you want to make that an answer?

I can install packages using PyCharm and the `pip install` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the other person [reinstalled their OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249879/cant-install-update-packages-with-python-pip-errno-20-not-a-directory#comment62117795_37249879) I imagine the only thing that really mattered was reinstalling pip.

The instructions to reinstall pip can be [found here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).  Assuming this issue is related to a bug in (your version of) pip running `get-pip.py` should fix the issue.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove python-pip python-dev` would work too if you want to manually uninstall python and pip before reinstalling them.