# Django installed in dist-packages

Tags: python, django, pip, yum

I am working on an Amazon Linux AMI (version 2013.09).
My goal, among other things, is to have Django up and running.
So here's what I do:

1. Install pip using yum (it installs pip 7.0.3 in Python2.7/dist-packages)
2. Install virtualenv using pip
3. Create a virtualenv (with --no-site-packages)
4. Install Django using pip inside the virtualenv (this installs Django in the virtenv's Python directory, inside dist-packages)

This seems fine, until I try to use manage.py. The following line:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -c -l > /dev/null
```

Invokes the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...my-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static'
```

Which is true, because the entire Django infrastructure is in **dist-packages**, not **site-packages**.
What is the correct way of fixing this dependency?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 28.06.15**
The reason Django attempts to access site-packages is the 'STATIC_ROOT' definition in its settings.py file.
Thing is, I installed Django in the exact same way, using the same settings, a couple of years ago, and it worked perfectly.
So what's changed? Why has pip suddenly moved to dist-packages?

Comment: Why should Django be in dist-packages? By definition, that's for things that are installed by the distribution's package manager. Anything installed by `pip` goes in site-packages.

Comment: I know, which is why I'm so baffled by this.

Comment: I came across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages) which could explain why pip installs packages into dist-packages.

Answer (score 7):

sometimes `PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT="amzn"` gets set in a shell and then stuff annoyingly goes into `dist-packages`.

To disable this annoyance,
`unset PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT`