# How can I create a simple system wide python library?

Tags: python

I see there are some built in packages that I can import from any script like:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
print today
```

How can I create a simple package and add it to the system library so that I can import it like `datetime` in the above example?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: The [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable determines what imports are available. So packages can be anywhere; you just need to specify where they are by setting that in the environment when you run `python`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to make a module.

Start by installing the `setuptools` package; on either Windows or Linux you should be able to type `pip install setuptools` at a terminal to get that installed. You should now be able to write `import setuptools` at a python prompt without getting an error.

Once that's working, set up a directory structure containing a `setup.py` and a folder for your project's code to go in. The directory must contain a file called `__init__.py`, which allows you to `import` the directory as though it's a file.

```
some_folder/
|    setup.py
|    my_project/__init__.py
```

In `setup.py`, drop the following content:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="My Awesome Project",
      version="0.0",
      packages=["my_project"])
```

In `my_project/__init__.py`, drop some stuff that you'd like to be able to import. Let's say...

```
# my_project/__init__.py
greeting = "Hello world!"
```

Now, in order to install the project at a system-wide level, run `python setup.py install`. Note that you'll need to run this as root if you're on Linux, since you're making changes to the system-wide python libraries.

After this, you should be able to run python from any directory you like and type:

```
>>> from my_project import greeting
>>> print greeting
Hello world!
>>>
```

Note that this is enough to tell you how to make a module, but there's one hell of a lot of stuff that `setuptools` can do for you. Take a look at https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html for more info on building stuff, and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html for more info on how modules actually work. If you'd like to look at a package that (I hope) is reasonably simple, then I made my [LazyLog module](https://github.com/Ymbirtt/python-lazylog) a couple of weeks ago on a train, and you're welcome to use it for reference.

Answer (score 7):

The quick way, if you're just making something for your own use and not worrying about packaging, is to put the module (which could be as simple as a single file) in your system's `site-packages` directory. (On Debian-based systems, [you probably want to use `dist-packages` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)).

To find out where your `site-packages`/`dist-packages` directory is, start Python and:

```
>>> from sys import path
>>> path
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py3.4.egg', '/usr/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-cygwin', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Note the last item in that example: `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages`. That's the sort of thing you're looking for. So in this example, if I save the following to `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/foo.py`:

```
def bar():
    print('Hello world!')
```

Then from anywhere on my system:

```
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar()
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a **package**, you can do it with [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html), which allows interacts with C++. You may implement algorithms using C++ and compile it as a Python lib. However it's poorly documented. And as [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) described, C API should be a basic option. Boost is built on C API any way.

[Sample](https://github.com/KHN190/tfidf): I made it several years ago on a class. You can do: `import tfidf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the module for personal use, just drop it in a folder and add that folder to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

For example, create a folder in your home directory called `~/python-packages`, then add the following line to your `.bashrc` (assuming you are using bash):

```
 export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python-packages`
```

Then, simply drop any modules/packages you want to make available in `~/python-packages`.

Answer (score -2):

Add you python script or package's path to sys.path or just move them to one of the location in sys.path.
BUT i do not suggest to do this...