# Tensorflow: why 'pip uninstall tensorflow' cannot find tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, uninstallation

I'm using Tensorflow-0.8 on Ubuntu14.04. I first install Tensorflow from sources and then setup Tensorflow for development according to the [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#setting-up-tensorflow-for-development). When I want to uninstall tensorflow using the following command

```
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
```

I encountered the following error:

```
Can't uninstall 'tensorflow'. No files were found to uninstall
```

Could anyone tell me where is wrong?

For your reference, the output of 
`pip show tensorflow` is

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.8.0
Location: /home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build
Requires: numpy, six, protobuf, wheel
```

But I actually find another Tensorflow directory at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow
```

Besides, I also have a question about the general usage of Python. I have seen two quite similar directories in my system, i.e.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Could any one tell me the differences between them? I noticed that everytime I use `sudo pip install <package>`, the package will be installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, could I instead install packages into `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` using `pip install`?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be because you didn't [install Tensorflow using `pip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation), but using `python setup.py develop` instead as your [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#setting-up-tensorflow-for-development) shows.

`pip uninstall` is likely to fail if the package is installed using `python setup.py install` as they do not leave behind metadata to determine what files were installed.

Therefore, you should be able to unistall Tensorflow with the option `-u` or `--unistall` of [`develop`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode)

```
cd /home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build
python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

To answer for the second (interestring) question  about the two `dist-package` created under `/usr/lib/python2.7` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` it exists already a [great Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages) on the topic.

PS: Tensorflow is a good library, you should consider *not* uninstall it :)

Comment: Haven't tried but looks like this should be the correct answer. @OP - can you check and comment/upvote if this works

Comment: @Max That's exactly where the problem lays. I successfully uninstalled Tensorflow in your way (and then reinstall it in virtualenv:) ). Thanks a lot for offering the solution and giving a good reference for my second question!

Comment: @ROBOT AI, My pleasure! I learn a lot of things myself while writing the answer. You said you want to install Tensorflow in`virtualenv`and there is nothing wrong with that. imo, I prefer [`Docker`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/). It could be more relevant for you as well.

Comment: None of these answers helped me in my Anaconda virtualenv. So what I did was `rm -rf tensor*` from the `site-packages` directory.

Comment: @GokulNC I don't think `rm -rf` is a good strategy: because you may still leave metadata somewhere else in you environment thus creating conflicts later on. I just read in [package remove](http://stuarteberg.github.io/conda-docs/using/pkgs.html#package-remove) from Anaconda's doc that `conda uninstall tensorflow` should just work. If you confirm this (e.g. with another package) I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: `conda uninstall tensorflow` didn't help, it says `PackageNotFoundError: Package(s) is missing from the environment:
            tensorflow` It's because I installed TF from the [official wheel using pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package), but pip doesn't seem to find it when I do `pip uninstall tensorflow`.

Answer (score 7):

I believe pip isn't installed for python2.7

try :

```
pip -V
```

On my system for instance it says :

```
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

So basically using `pip uninstall` will only remove packages for python3.4 (and not python2.7).

So I don't use pip binary as such, and rather, call pip module from inside python.

In your case :

```
python2.7 -m pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! The results of `pip -V` is `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. Then I guess pip may have been installed for python2.7, isn't it? Then I also try `python2.7 -m pip uninstall tensorflow`, but the same error remains.