# ImportError in Python

Tags: python, importerror

I tried to execute a program using geonames_rdf, but I cant execute it by this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "geo1.py", line 13, in <module>
 import geonames.config.log
ImportError: No module named config.log
```

I read several posts abot ImportError and I check the path of the system and it is correct. I'm working in a VirtualBox with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.

The imports of my program are:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import logging
import geonames.config.log
import geonames.compat
import geonames.adapters.search
```

I've also tried add this line:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonames/')
```

The command that I used to instal this package was

```
sudo pip install geonames_rdf
```

Comment: You might try `from geonames import config` `from config import log` to narrow down what the problem is

Comment: try `import geonames ; print(geonames.__file__)` to see what file/module you import. Maybe you have somewhere `geonames.py` and you import this file.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I tried your line and the error is with `from geonames import config`

Comment: @furas when I have tried your code I see I'm importing  __init__.pyc

Comment: do you see full path to `__init__.pyc` ? if not then it imports local file. Maybe you have local folder  `geonames`

Comment: @furas the full path is: `/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geonames/__init__.pcy`

Comment: @furas in that folder there are also a geonames.pyc, do you think that geonames.pyc is the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending site-packages not dist-packages.  A bit of searching it looks like dist-packages is debian specific.

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geonames/')

**Reason:**

Since you're installing 3rd party python package via pip it will not go into dist-packages and python rightfully cannot find it on the path.

Reference link:
[What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)

Comment: The foldersite-packages is empty, how can I install geonames there? Thank you for your help:)

Comment: @GonzaloMolina I would try doing a "which python" in your shell.  If your are in a virtualenv the path may be different.  I would navigate to the folder and visually verify that the folders are there.  doing a "sudo pip install geonames" should install it for you correctly.  Thats odd

Comment: I'm not using a virtualenv... how can I show you my folders?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to use geonames_rdf, but I didn't know I needed it to do a geonames search so I installed geonames first, then discovered I had to install fiona and gdal (I'm on Windows, had to install these two using prebuilt whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Don't know why these dependencies aren't baked into geonames.

Anyway once I then installed geonames_rdf it seemed to install into the geonames folder in c:\Python27\lib\site-packages, added at least the adapters package. In c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\geonames there is a config folder with log.py in it.