# ImportError: No module named google.oauth2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I wanted to add a google.cloud.storage dependency to my project so I tried to install this dependency with

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`

Running my app again with dev_appserver, it shows me that my gcloud components needed to be updated. Ok so, `gcloud components update`

And in my `src/__init__.py` file, I got the code that tells gcloud in which folder to look for dependencies like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('src/libs')
```

All the dependencies are installed correctly, except that I'm getting the error `ImportError: No module named google.oauth2`

PS: My app is using OAuth2 to secure access to the API. And it was working correctly before I do a components update, now even if I rollback code, remove the libs folder and install again dependencies, I still got the No module error, and it seems like dev_appserver is not looking for that dependency inside the libs folder !

Here's the result of `gcloud --version`:

```
Google Cloud SDK 188.0.1
app-engine-python 1.9.66
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.63
bq 2.0.28
core 2018.02.08
gsutil 4.28
```

And here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/login/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/login/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/login/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/headless/Documents/Projects/meterFleet/app-backend/src/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.app.user.api import UserApi
  File "/home/headless/Documents/Projects/meterFleet/app-backend/src/app/user/api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.googleapis.iam import getIamPolicy, addIapUser, deleteIapUser
  File "/home/headless/Documents/Projects/meterFleet/app-backend/src/googleapis/iam.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.common.authentication import OAuth
  File "/home/headless/Documents/Projects/meterFleet/app-backend/src/common/authentication.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
  File "/home/login/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1147, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.oauth2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: I think you never get this error if you use something like virtualenv.**

The problem was coming from the dependencies being installed in both the project folder (in the `src/libs` folder), and in the python local libs folder (/usr/local/python2.7/dist-packages). I removed the google libraries from the python libs folder and it's now working again !

Comment: With me the google packages are in .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. It probably [depends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46771967/4878398) on how you installed python/pip. Which packages did you remove? Can any harm be done to your system by removing packages?

Answer (score 13):

I've had this issue quite a bit. I uninstalled all Google packages from my local machine, deleted the lib folder in my GAE app folder, created it again then executed:

```
pip install -t lib google-auth google-auth-httplib2 google-api-python-client --upgrade
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just upgrading some python packages solved my issue:

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth google-auth-httplib2 google-api-python-client
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use pipenv to solve this issue.

```
pip3 install pipenv
pipenv install
pipenv shell
```

Then install the libraries you need.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because the file itself was called `google.py`, so it was trying to import itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had virtualenv created and was trying to run a script where you insert data into google cloud bigquery with a service account and automate it using cron file , the solution for me was to replace usr/local/bin/python to my virtualenv python path.

old cron file :

30 11 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /opt/deployment/cronJobs/ProjectAssetMetrics/daily/updateCCMSCountJob.py > /opt/deployment/cronJobs/ProjectAssetMetrics/daily/updateCCMSCountJob.log 2>&1
in your

new cron file :

16 12 * * * /opt/.envs/sl_dw/bin/python3 /opt/deployment/cronJobs/ProjectAssetMetrics/daily/updateCCMSCountJob.py > /opt/deployment/cronJobs/ProjectAssetMetrics/daily/updateCCMSCountJob.log 2>&

You can check your python path by typing:

$ which python

make sure you activate your virtualenv if any

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the above works for you - I found [this answer](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/169#issuecomment-315417916) from GitHub by hiranya911. It solved my problem perfectly.