# Unable to install docker-compose with pip, "ImportError: No module named dockerpycreds"

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-compose, dockerpy

I tried to install `docker-compose` using `pip` but I'm getting this error:

```
$ docker-compose
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
      from compose.cli.main import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", 
      line 17, in <module>
      from . import errors
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
      packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 11, in <module>
      from docker.errors import APIError
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/__init__.py", 
      line 2, in <module>
      from .api import APIClient
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
      packages/docker/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
      from .client import APIClient
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
      packages/docker/api/client.py", line 11, in <module>
      from .build import BuildApiMixin
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", 
      line 6, in <module>
      from .. import auth
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 
      6, in <module>
    import dockerpycreds ImportError: No module named dockerpycreds
```

Update 1: after installing docker_pycreds, as mentioned by an answer, it led me to another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", 
    line 17, in <module>
    from . import errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", 
    line 11, in <module>
    from docker.errors import APIError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/__init__.py", 
    line 2, in <module>
    from .api import APIClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
    packages/docker/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .client import APIClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", 
    line 11, in <module>
    from .build import BuildApiMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", 
    line 9, in <module>
    from .. import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
    packages/docker/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .build import tar, exclude_paths
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/build.py", 
    line 4, in <module>
    from .utils import create_archive
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", 
    line 18, in <module>
    from .. import tls
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/tls.py", line 5,   
    in <module>
    from .transport import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
    packages/docker/transport/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ssladapter import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
    packages/docker/transport/ssladapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    urllib3.connection.match_hostname = match_hostname
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

Update 2: after `pip install -U urllib3==1.14` as pointed out by another answer, error changed to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", 
    line 17, in <module>
    from . import errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", 
    line 13, in <module>
    from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout
  ImportError: cannot import name ReadTimeout
```

Comment: did you install packages in virtual env??

Comment: no, @jesuisgenial

Comment: pip install -U urllib3==1.14

Comment: try above let me know does it help

Comment: Error changed to: ImportError: cannot import name ReadTimeout, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need this package installed.

```
pip install docker_pycreds
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/python-dockerpycreds

https://github.com/shin-/dockerpy-creds/blob/master/dockerpycreds/constants.py

Since you are on a Debian derivative, it will go in your dist-packages.
See this post for details on dist/site-packages.

[What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)

EDIT:

you might need to update dependencies.

```
pip install urllib3==1.21
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade urllib3
```

and/or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: After doing that, it led me to another error


```AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'```

Comment: Hum, that worked for me (I tested prior to posting but I am on OSX). I will see if I can find any info about the current state.

Comment: According to this post I found if you update your urllib3, that might help.
"pip install urllib3==1.14"
this might not be the latest version so I would look to see what the latest is. This is odd that pip is not automatically updating dependencies. The post: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/1054

Comment: What version of pip do you have installed? The reason I found your post is I had a few issues that lead me here and I had to update pip. "pip install --upgrade pip" BTW: you will see many posts with sudo on pip and it is not recommended to do that. If you need sudo then you have installed things incorrectly.