# Cannot run paho mqtt client -> "ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client"

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am trying to set up an mqtt client, but I am getting an ImportError:

I installed paho with:

```
pip install paho-mqtt
```

It said: `Successfully installed dnspython-1.15.0 paho-mqtt-1.3.1 python-etcd-0.4.5 urllib3-1.22`

But when I am trying to call my python script with `sudo python listen.py` it says:

```
File "listen.py", line 6, in <module>
  import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client
```

When I am typing `python --version` it says: `Python 2.7.13` and when I call `pip freeze` paho is listed `paho-mqtt==1.3.1`

Any suggestions what's wrong?

Comment: Can you run `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` as regular user, and with `sudo` and check if outputs are different?

Comment: With `sudo` it says: 
`['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
`

Comment: Without it says: `['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the library "paho" has been installed (for default) in the folder "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" but "sudo python" search this library in the folder "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages".
I have solved with one link:

> cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>
> sudo ln -s /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho

Now my script run also with "sudo"

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you. When `paho` was installed for default, how sould it be installed instead? `sudo pip install paho-mqtt` ??

Comment: No, read this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution is to install the library in the specific directory

```
cd <directory>
sudo pip install paho-mqtt -t ./
```