# How to make Python read from local dist-packages or site-packages instead of global dist-packages? ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cosmos'

Tags: python, azure

First of all, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239729/1845207) explains three python package locations nicely, I am giving a brief summary of them first, in my case for the azure-cosmos python package these are:

First, **Global** dist-packages, controlled with **sudo apt-get** (before installing a newer version with pip3 it shows ver 3.1.1):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-azure-cosmos
...
$ pip3 list -v | grep azure-cos
azure-cosmos 3.1.1 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Second, **Local** dist-packages, installing with **sudo pip3**

```
$ sudo pip3 install -U azure-cosmos
...
$ pip3 list -v | grep azure-cos
azure-cosmos 4.2.0 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages pip
```

Third, **Local** site-packages, (removed with sudo pip and then) installed with **pip3** (without sudo)

```
$ sudo pip3 install -U azure-cosmos
...
$ pip3 list -v | grep azure-cos
azure-cosmos 4.2.0 /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages pip
```

However, in all three cases my Python is looking ONLY in the (first) global dist-packages (that contains an older package version):

```
$ python3 -c "from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'CosmosClient' from 'azure.cosmos' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cosmos/__init__.py)
```

I do have $PATH and $PYTHONPATH set properly to include the local dist-packages and local site-packages locations, Python actually shows them in sys.path **before** global dist-packages:

```
$ python3 -c "import sys; print([p for p in sys.path])"
['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

---

So why is Python taking the old version of azure-cosmos that came with the distro instead of getting a newer version that I have installed with pip? What am I missing here?

(I did try to update the python3-azure-cosmos package but 3.1.1 seems to be highest available via apt-get, and that's not the point of the question)

---

An easy solution is to remove the GLOBAL dist-packages version, one can simply run:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python3-azure-cosmos
```

Then Python magically uses a version from either local dist-packages or site-packages from my home dir (package installed via sudo pip3 or pip3 respectively), because the package does not exist in global dist-packages.

But... my problem is that **I cannot run sudo in this case**. So I cannot remove the global package. Halp.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below command to Uninstall/Remove the packages without using **sudo** privileges
`rm -rf <Package_Directory>`

Linux **rm -rf** is a powerful command **deletes directory forcefully**. It means a file or directory will be removed. Even though it has `read-only` permission.

Comment: Without sudo I don't have permissions to remove from /ust/lib/python3/dist-packages

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround (but not a solution) to this and [a similar issue I had one day later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161779/python3-6-m-pip-install-upgrade-azure-cosmos-4-2-0-from-azure-cosmos-impo) is to just use a python virtual environment, e.g. using `pipenv`:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pipenv
$ pipenv install azure-cosmos
$ pipenv run python -c "from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient"
```

And we have empty output so there is no import error anymore, meaning that it works.