# python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade azure-cosmos > 4.2.0 > from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cosmos'

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When I try to import CosmosClient from azure.cosmos, I get a ModuleNotFoundError, like the azure-cosmos library was not installed:

```
$ python3.6 -c "from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cosmos'
```

I'm using Linux with Python 3.6 I am trying to import CosmosClient from the azure-cosmos library. I have installed azure-cosmos in version 4.2.0 using `python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade azure-cosmos`, then:

```
$ python3.6 -m pip show azure-cosmos

Name: azure-cosmos
Version: 4.2.0
Summary: Microsoft Azure Cosmos Client Library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: askdocdb@microsoft.com
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: six, azure-core
```

The `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` folder is present in sys.path:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import sys; print([p for p in sys.path])"

['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

This is similar to [a problem I had yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145482/how-to-make-python-read-from-local-dist-packages-or-site-packages-instead-of-glo), where a lower version of the library from global dist-packages was shadowing a higher version in local dist-packages, but this time the azure-cosmos package is not installed globally in dist-packages:

```
$ apt-get remove python3-azure-cosmos
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3-azure-cosmos
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround (but not a solution) to this and [another similar issue I had a day before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145482/how-to-make-python-read-from-local-dist-packages-or-site-packages-instead-of-glo) is to just use a python virtual environment, e.g. using `pipenv`:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pipenv
$ pipenv install azure-cosmos
$ pipenv run python -c "from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient"
```

And we have empty output so there is no import error anymore, meaning that it works.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try pip list to see all the packages you installed?

Comment: Just tried it and it shows the package in version 4.2.0, same as command pip show azure-cosmos that I mentioned. I wouldn't expect pip show and pip list to have different output.