# The site-packages folder exists for python2 but not python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

As the root user I see:

```
root@5d6f29f1d4e9:/usr/local/lib/python2.7# ls -a
.  ..  dist-packages  site-packages
root@5d6f29f1d4e9:/usr/local/lib/python3.6# ls -a
.  ..  dist-packages
```

and when I run this:

```
find / -type d -name 'site-packages'
```

the only result is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

does anyone know why I wouldn't see site-packages in 3.6?

I installed python3 with:

```
 apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
 apt install -y python3-pip
```

and then installed a bunch of python package using:

```
 pip3 install gunicorn
 pip3 install wheel
 ...etc...
```

maybe  I didn't install python3 well?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages

Comment: I don't think that question talks about 2.7 vs 3.x tho?

Comment: What is the output of `pip3 show gunicorn`?

Comment: What distribution are you using? did you build Python yourself?

Comment: I installed just like the OP says

Comment: Exec updatedb ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be Debian feature with dist-packages instead of site-packages.
You can check the path for your pip3 installed packages: `python3 -c "import wheel;print(wheel.__file__)"`

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to find where the python is installing your packages, then read on.

1. Just open the python console using `python3`.
2. Check whether you can import your package directly. (When I say directly, I mean without any virtualenv etc) `import gunicorn`
3. Now, in the console if it is working without errors, that means your python3 can find the package.
4. If you think where the python looks for packages, the obvious solution to occur would be to use `sys.path`
5. So `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)` That should give you a list of folders not more than 10. Just navigate through the folders and you will find the path where packages are installed by default.

**OR** 
Simply run `python3 -m site`