# Pip says it installs mysqlclient successfully, but cannot find it or uninstall it

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I am running into the following issue trying to install mysqlclient as part of getting a Django project up and running on an AWS EC2 instance.

In a `python 3.8.5` virtual environment:

```
(venv3)$ which pip
~/venv3/bin/pip

(venv3)$ pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/venv3/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

(venv3)$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-2.0.3
```

I try running the Django Shell:

```
(venv3)$ python manage.py shell
...full trace stack truncated for brevity...
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

So I tried to find where pip installed it, and it seems to not actually be installed or be a trace of it anywhere:

```
(venv3)$ pip show mysqlclient
WARNING: Package(s) not found: mysqlclient

(venv3)$ pip freeze | grep -i mysqlclient
<nothing>

(venv3)$ sudo find / -name mysqlclient
<nothing>
```

Then as a sanity check I apparently successfully install it but then pip can't find it to uninstall it:

```
(venv3)$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-2.0.3

(venv3)$ pip uninstall mysqlclient
WARNING: Package(s) not found: mysqlclient
```

Other things I have tried/verified

- Making sure python is the 64-bit version
- Checking pip outside of the virtual environment
- Nuking the virtual environment and starting again
- Trying to install specific versions of `mysqlclient`
- Installing and importing/using any other python package

EDIT: Wanted to add that I have also deleted the pip cache and it still does not work.

Comment: maybe try `pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall mysqlclient `

Comment: Same output, gives installation success message but it's no where to be found

Comment: what happens with `python -c "import mysqlclient"`? Can you use it to connect to your database outside of django? are you sure you have a your database information and credentials properly specified?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError. Database information/credentials are fine, they work on this machine and locally. This is just an issue getting Django/python3 to connect to mysql

Comment: Try running pip in verbose mode. Does it log anything?

Comment: @user202729 It logged nothing out of the ordinary, but your comment led to my solution, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question because I finally figured it out.

As per @user202729's comment I ran pip in verbose mode `pip install mysqlclient --verbose` which didn't itself show anything out of the ordinary as far as I could tell, but did show that `mysqlclient` and `MySQLdb` related files were being installed in `/dist-packages` which was not being picked my by my python installation. I copied the `MySQLdb` directory from `venv3/lib64/python3.8/dist-packages` to `venv3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages` and that solved the `python` and `django` issues.

Comment: "copy"? That will definitely solve the problem (as well as manually extract the source files into the correct directory), but it's still not clear what's the underlying issue.

Comment: With some searching there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages (it doesn't explain much), but it's likely because of some environment variable, pip configuration or misconfigured PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I figured it was one of the two but had been banging my head against the wall long enough that this works for now. I came across the same question which only inspired the solution and did not explain it.