# error then import pytorch-lightning, azure notebook

Tags: python, azure, pytorch

i am use microsoft azure (for students) ML servise. Then i work with notebook i can not import pytorch-lightning libary.

```
!pip install pytorch-lightning==0.9.0 
import pytorch_lightning as pl
```

Here i have error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <module>
----> 2 import pytorch_lightning as pl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning'
```

This is unbearably weird. someone faced such a problem?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: for me it is no longer relevant, I completed the experiments on colab

Answer (score 1):

This is rather strange but could be related to that your installation is in another location, so let's:

1. try where is PL installed with `find -name "lightning"`
2. also, check what is the loaded package locations `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

I guess that the problem will be in [What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by [installing PyTorch-lightning in the kernel](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/13145) instead of the machine. It all boils down to installing with `%conda` magic instead of `!conda` magic (or same thing for `%pip` magic instead of `!pip` magic).