# add2virtualenv (virtualenv wrapper) does not work with scipy

Tags: python, macos, scipy, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I want to create a virtualenv without global python packages, but with the scipy distribution that is shared; installing scipy takes quite a while and I don't want to go through the motions too often.

So I run `add2virtualenv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy` and after running add2virtualenv it shows the directory is added. (I doublechecked, it is the right directory).
Then I issue `workon myfile` to be sure the working directories are reloaded. 
However, when I try to load scipy, it is an `ImportError: No module named scipy`. This is unexpected.

Has anyone used a global scipy in a non-global-sitepackages virtualenv?

Comment: add2virtualenv add the specified directory to PYTHONPATH. You should therefore add your entire site-package to import scipy.

Comment: An alternative solution should be symlinking scipy directory inside virtual env's site-package

Comment: Thank you. So I misinterpreted the way add2virtualenv should be used. Is there no command that makes it easy to add a specific package? (other than symlinking?)

Comment: I don't know how virtualenvwrapper works, but I don't think so... Symlinking to me seems a good solution. After all, many modules inside virtualenv's site-package are symlinked.

Comment: what I typically do is create one 'base' virtualenv with `--no-system-site-packages`, pip install scipy, numpy etc. in it, then use `cpvirtualenv` to clone it whenever I want a new 'throwaway' virtualenv to mess around with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to summarize, the actual problem here is that the directory including the packages to be imported must be used, instead of the specific package. That is, instead of

```
add2virtualenv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy
```

It should be

```
add2virtualenv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Beware: this solution has the drawback that you do not only include scipy, but any other packages in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.

---

An alternate, space-efficent solution could be symlinking scipy directory inside the virtual env's site-package. This can be done, in your virtual env, through:

```
cdsitepackages
ln -s /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy scipy
```

---

*All credits go to @rubik (see the comments)*

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) answer to find your site-packages path in case it is different than the one used here.