# Why is pip trying to re-install numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Following ([add2virtualenv (virtualenv wrapper) does not work with scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518729/add2virtualenv-virtualenv-wrapper-does-not-work-with-scipy)) I symlinked my `site-packages` `numpy` directory into my virtualenv `site-packages`. In my virtualenv, I can do `import numpy` with no problems.

However, when I try to do `pip install pandas` in the virtualenv, `pip` tries to re-install `numpy`. How can I make `pip` recognize that `numpy` is already installed?

Comment: would it be easier just copy over numpy to the site-packages in your venv? Or just create a venv with access to your system packages `--system-site-packages`

Comment: Would copying vs symlinking change anything? I don't want to pull everything in with `--system-site-packages`, just numpy and scipy which are a pain to install in Ubuntu (because you have to set up all the BLAS/LaPack stuff properly)

Comment: well copying numpy from your system to you venv with a simple `cp -r `should certainly work, I would have thought a symlink would have also but I have never done it.

Comment: Going into my virtualenv site-packages directory and doing `cp -r /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy ./` did not change anything. `pip list` still does not show numpy and installing pandas still tries to re-install numpy.

Comment: did  you copy the `egg-info`?

Comment: Once the egg and numpy dir is copied over your should have no issue and pip list should show numpy, the egg is important. just copying that alone will make pip think it is installed but obviously without copying the package dir you won't be able to use it

Comment: Ah, copying the `egg-info` fixed it! If you want to add that as an answer I will mark it accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can copy the `.egg` and the module directory into your virtualenv site-packages directory:

```
sudo cp -r  path_to_system/numpy your_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
sudo cp -r  path_to_system/numpy-x.x.x-pyx.x.egg-info  your_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```