# How do I install Socks / SocksIPy on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, socks

I am new to python and would like to install `SocksIPy` on Ubuntu (running within a VirtualBox vm). The README says to place the `socks.py` file into my `lib/site-packages` directory. I do not know where to locate this directory. The Terminal command  `python socks.py install` from the root runs, but does not install correctly (error "No module named socks" when I run `import socks` in a python script)

SocksIPy link
http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/

Can someone suggest a way to get socks/socksipy running on my machine?
Thanks!

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory it will help you to find site-packages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest way to install it - provided the VM has working Internect connectivity - would likely be to let `apt-get` do it for you. From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-socksipy
```

It's in the universe repository, which should be enabled by default. If not, you can [enable it yourself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

Comment: Got it -- had tried this earlier and it broke...I think your syntax was 'more correct' than mine. Thanks!

Comment: How would I go about doing it with pip? say, if i want to do it only in virtualenv?
`pip search socks` shows SocksiPy as an existing package, but pip install SocksiPy fails.

Comment: @eran you can try `pip install SocksiPy-branch`

Comment: @Anshul: `SocksiPy-branch` seems broken e.g., [stem tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) works with `python-socksipy` but [breaks with `SocksiPy-branch` due to stack overflow in `sendall()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28790000/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Ohk. Thanks for the update. I don't remember exactly why I used it in first place but worked fine for my limited use case of a prototype back then.

Comment: The solution in the other answer from @J.F.Sebastian works better in a virtualenv

Answer (score 17):

[`PySocks`](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks) is yet another `SocksiPy` fork:

```
$ pip install PySocks
```

It works on Python 2/3.

Answer (score 1):

For Python3

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-socks
```