# Tor Stem - To Russia With Love Connection Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor, stem

I am trying to get the [To Russia With Love tutoial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) from the Stem project working.

```
from io import StringIO
import socket
import urllib3
import time

import socks  # SocksiPy module
import stem.process

from stem.util import term

SOCKS_PORT = 9150

# Set socks proxy and wrap the urllib module

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo


def query(url):
  """
  Uses urllib to fetch a site using SocksiPy for Tor over the SOCKS_PORT.
  """

  try:
    return urllib3.urlopen(url).read()
  except:
    return "Unable to reach %s" % url


# Start an instance of Tor configured to only exit through Russia. This prints
# Tor's bootstrap information as it starts. Note that this likely will not
# work if you have another Tor instance running.

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print (term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE))


print (term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  tor_cmd = "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\\tor.exe", config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
#    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
  }, 
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)

print (term.format("\nChecking our endpoint:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))
print (term.format(query("https://www.atagar.com/echo.php"), term.Color.BLUE))

tor_process.kill()  # stops tor
```

I have tweaked it a bit from the original to get it working with python 3.4 and I am also using pysocks instead of socksipy.  I started with urllib instead of urllib3 and I had the same issue.  Currently I am getting:

```
C:\Python>python program1.py
←[1mStarting Tor:
←[0m
←[34mFeb 28 21:59:45.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting←[0m
←[34mFeb 28 21:59:45.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server←[0m
←[34mFeb 28 21:59:45.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network←[0m
←[34mFeb 28 21:59:45.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop←[0m
←[34mFeb 28 21:59:46.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit←[0m
←[34mFeb 28 21:59:47.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done←[0m
←[1m
Checking our endpoint:
←[0m
←[34mUnable to reach https://www.atagar.com/echo.php←[0m
```

I have had similar code work outside of tor.  I can connect my tor browser to this site and I can browse to it with no problems.  I have tried changing the port numbers, but this is the one that is set up in Tor's proxy settings.  One thought I had is that this may be a timing issue.  Is it possible that the code is not waiting long enough to the site to respond?

Any help in getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unrelated: install `colorama` to display ANSI colors in Windows console.

Comment: you should include the link to [the `stem` package tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html). Does it work unmodified on your machine?

Comment: It does not work unmodified on my machine. I was able to get the code sample below working, thanks for posting that. Still not sure what was wrong with my originally pasted code.

Comment: if you had to change the code in my answer to make it work on Windows then post your code as an answer -- it may be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version of [the stem tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) that uses [`pysocks`](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks) and its `sockshandler` module to avoid monkey-patching the socket module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html

Usage:
  russian-tor-exit-node [<tor>] [--color] [--geoipfile=</path/to/file>]
  russian-tor-exit-node -h | --help
  russion-tor-exit-node --version

Dependencies:

- tor (packaged and standalone executables work)
- pip install stem
- pip install PySocks
- pip install docopt
  : parse options
- pip install colorama
  : cross-platform support for ANSI colors
- [optional] sudo apt-get tor-geoipdb
  : if tor is bundled without geoip files; --geoipfile=/usr/share/tor/geoip
"""
import sys
from contextlib import closing

import colorama  # $ pip install colorama
import docopt  # $ pip install docopt
import socks  # $ pip install PySocks
import stem.process  # $ pip install stem
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler  # see pysocks repository
from stem.util import term

try:
    import urllib2
except ImportError: # Python 3
    import urllib.request as urllib2


args = docopt.docopt(__doc__, version='0.2')
colorama.init(strip=not (sys.stdout.isatty() or args['--color']))

tor_cmd = args['<tor>'] or 'tor'
socks_port = 7000
config = dict(SocksPort=str(socks_port), ExitNodes='{ru}')
if args['--geoipfile']:
    config.update(GeoIPFile=args['--geoipfile'], GeoIPv6File=args['--geoipfile']+'6')


def query(url, opener=urllib2.build_opener(
        SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", socks_port))):
  try:
      with closing(opener.open(url)) as r:
          return r.read().decode('ascii')
  except EnvironmentError as e:
    return "Unable to reach %s: %s" % (url, e)

# Start an instance of Tor configured to only exit through Russia. This prints
# Tor's bootstrap information as it starts. Note that this likely will not
# work if you have another Tor instance running.
def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print(term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE))
  else:
    print(line)

print(term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd=tor_cmd,
    config=config,
    init_msg_handler=print_bootstrap_lines,
)
try:
    print(term.format("\nChecking our endpoint:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))
    print(term.format(query("https://icanhazip.com"), term.Color.BLUE))
finally:
    if tor_process.poll() is None: # still running
        tor_process.terminate()  # stops tor
        tor_process.wait()
```

It works on both Python 2 and 3 on my Ubuntu machine.

`strace` shows data and dns requests are made via the tor proxy.

Comment: Do you think you could look at my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911103/accessing-youtube-via-stem-tor-gives-unable-to-reach-url-error), I seem to be having similar issues. Would appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted by @J.F.Sebastian gives error on Python 3.4, and it can be fixed, but here is working code WITH PyCurl surely like in stem example.

```
import pycurl
import stem.process
import io

SOCKS_PORT = 9150

print("Starting Tor:\n")

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print(line)

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    #'ExitNodes': '{au}',
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)

output = io.BytesIO()

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt( pycurl.URL, 'http://www.example.com' )
curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXY, 'localhost' )
curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXYPORT, SOCKS_PORT )
curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5 )
curl.setopt( pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, output.write)
curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest', 'referer: http://www.meendo.net/?partner=13026'])
#curl.set_option(pycurl.USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36")
curl.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)

curl.perform()

print("RESULT : " + output.getvalue().decode('ascii'))

tor_process.kill()  # stops tor
output.close() # free used memory
```

Comment: the code from my answer works as is on Python 3.4. As it is said in the answer, I've tested it on both Python 2 and 3.