# Instagram page would not load through urlopen() with Tor. What may be the reason/fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, tor

I am checking an Instagram page existence by `urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/profile-name')`. Getting a profile page when it exists, and 404 error if not. That's a perfect flow.

But the Instagram request limit is reached fast. It is per-ip, so I need to change IP. For this I've tried Tor. And... it gets broken, when I start doing `urlopen()` through Tor connection - getting the Instagram login page disregarding profile existence, so I cannot distinct existing/non-existing profiles. What may be reason for such behavior and how to fix it?

Here is the sample code. Run in `python3`. `USE_TOR` constant will switch Tor on/off. To install `socks` run in terminal `pip3 install requests requests[socks]` and `pip3 install pysocks`.

You need to install Tor before use it.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import socks
import socket

USE_TOR = True

def createConnection(address, timeout = None, source_address = None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

def getIp():
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip") as page:
        return str(page.read()).replace('\n', '')

#

print("Normal IP: " + getIp())

# Set up tor

if USE_TOR:
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    socket.create_connection = createConnection
    print("Tor IP: " + getIp())

# Request page

try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/a')
    print("Profile exists")
except HTTPError as e:
    print("Profile does not exist. Http error " + str(e.code))
```

Terminal output:

`USE_TOR = True`

```
Normal IP: b'{\n  "origin": "my ip"\n}\n'
Tor IP: b'{\n  "origin": "158.174.122.199, 158.174.122.199"\n}\n'
Profile exists
```

`USE_TOR = False`

```
Normal IP: b'{\n  "origin": "my ip"\n}\n'
Profile does not exist. Http error 404
```

*`"my ip"` differs from the Tor one.

Comment: please include your terminal output too

Comment: @Amit output added

Comment: @SaSha What package is `import socks`?  When trying to test your code, I get a *ModuleNotFoundError*.

Comment: @CalebGoodman To install socks run in terminal: `pip3 install requests requests[socks]` and `pip3 install pysocks`

Comment: @SaSha I have all of those packages installed, but I still get the same error.  Are you sure that `import socks` works on your end?  I'm thinking it might be `from <some_package) import socks` or something.

Comment: @CalebGoodman 100% sure. This script is running for me, copied & tested just now. Maybe it require some extra installation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820453/how-do-i-install-socks-socksipy-on-ubuntu (can't remember).

Answer (score 0):

Try loading profile with instaloader. If you dont get error profile exists. You can use try catch.

```
#instagram.py
from instaloader import Instaloader
from instaloader import Profile

L = Instaloader()
profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, "amit")
#output <Profile amit (27235560)>

profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, "dasjkhkdhsjkahdjkashdadkajksdha")
#yields error.so you know profile doesnot exist
```

Comment: Thanks. But this not helps. This code is redirected to Instagram login page, disregarding profile exists or not. So I cannot distinguish existing/non-existing profiles.

Comment: Check the edit. You can achieve that with instaloader . https://instaloader.github.io/as-module.html#profiles

Comment: Will not help, as https://instaloader.github.io/troubleshooting.html#too-many-requests this library also encounter 'too many requsts', same as urllib I am currently using. Instagram just sends me login page when limit is reached. The main question is how to cheat the limit. It is per-ip, so I need to change IP. I know how to change IP using Tor or proxy, BUT in this case instagram instantly redirects me to the login page, instead of user page or 404. My goal is to resolve exactly Tor/proxy problem.

Comment: Also, `requests` library somehow started returning me real user pages, so I deleted info that `requests` does not work.

Comment: I use instaloader for a lot of projects.I normally have never had any issue. I guess you need to send large number of requests. If you want to change proxy for each request or maybe rotate proxy. 

You can setup http proxy in environment variables. 
instaloader uses "requests" library under the hood. So it it will use the proxy from environment variables. I guess you can try that approach.

Comment: It gives 500 requests/day or so. I'll try set up env variable.