# ImportError: No module named statsmodels.api

Tags: python, python-import, statsmodels

I'm new in python and have this problem. I have install Pandas, Numpy, Scipy, and I install Stats Models with apt-get install python-statsmodels, but when I try to use:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

But I have this problem:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6030a6549dc0> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm

ImportError: No module named statsmodels.api
```

Why??

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 12.04, statsmodels is installed through scikits.

Hence:

```
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from statsmodels import api as sm
```

Comment: The error is the same:  ImportError: No module named statsmodels

Comment: Try 'import statsmodels'. If that fails it is not installed correctly. Try to see if it is present in the site-packages dir of your python install. Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: No, I don't use virtualenv. And when I try 'import statsmodels' the error continuous. where I see the site-packages?? Is in /usr/lib/python2.7??

Comment: `from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())` seems to be: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on ubuntu.

Comment: on Ubuntu it [seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) to be: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Comment: StatsModels don't are in dist-packages, but I install with apt-get, I need install with pip?? or how i do to install in dist-packages?

Comment: try pip. that normally installs in dist-packages.

Comment: I install with pip, but install in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages an not in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, and the problem continuos, this is the problem?? how I say where do I install it?

Comment: That is the problem, you cant tell tell it where to install. What you could try is copy all `statsmodels` stuff from `/usr/local/lib/dist-packages` to `/usr/lib/dist-packages` since they are using the same python version.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same, error, and the following needs to be installed
statsmodels - Statistical computation models for use with scipy.

Answer (score 0):

It requires Stats module to be istalled...

Python command#
!pip3 install statsmodels

Reference#
https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/

Answer (score -1):

For the current version you could use a binary installer:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/binaries/