# Installing EWSWrapper?

Tags: python-2.7, installation, exchangewebservices

How to install ewswrapper for python off of their site on a windows, (sadly), 64 bit machine with python 2.7. 
[The Link to the site is here.](http://ewswrapper.lafiel.net/)
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally recommended way to install python packages is using a package manager like `pip` or (gasp) `easy_install`. However, there are a few exceptions like this one.

On Windows, there may be a pre-built package for you to download. In this case, the link is http://ewswrapper.lafiel.net/index.php?al3x_download=file&userid=PUBLIC&filepath=/PYTHON_Releases/_PYTHON_2012_02_09_EWSWrapper_v_0_2.7z.

You'll need to unzip the file with 7zip, and place the resulting directory in your site-packages path. You can locate your system's site-packages path by looking at this SO answer: [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

Additionally, EWSWrapper will require a few dependencies that you should be able to get in pip.

```
pip.exe install python-ntlm suds
```

If you don't have `pip`, you can install it: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Just so you know, this isn't the normal way a package is installed. Perhaps someone should let them know...