# Edit installed package in Python

Tags: python, package

I found an error on one python package I use. How can I edit this error? Is only one line of code in one file. I tried posting on Github, but the author ignores me.

For other reasons I can't uninstall the package, I have to edit, but I don't know where I can find the package, and if I do, I don't know what I should do to save the changes.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

Comment: have you looked in the source directory?

Comment: But I want to know how can apply the changes

Comment: edit the .py file that you need to change

Comment: But the changes are not applying. I have to restart something?

Comment: what exactly have you changed?

Comment: One parameter in a function.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The files .pyc and .pyo are not generating.

Comment: So you have no .pyc in the module dir?

Comment: I deleted them after I change the line. But now they are not regenerating.

Comment: re run your code that does the import.  The .pyc file won't be created until the code is imported