# SciPy special functions source and citations

Tags: scipy

I would like to know where I can find the original source of the algorithms used in the various Bessel functions within scipy.special (jn, yn, kn, in), so that I could cite them, as well as read about them. I'd also like to understand the limits of reliability (e.g. high orders and very large or small arguments). I'm guessing I could start by reading the citations. I understand that I'll also have to learn about how to deal with very large and small values within python itself.

If the source code (C?) is viewable within my Python and/or SciPy installation, it would be great to understand how I could find it! I'm using python but not familiar with its installation - I really just dragged the python and scipy icons into the applications folder icon a year ago, and haven't looked since.  (I'm using python 2.7 on OSX).

If this is already available somewhere I haven't found, a link to that would also be appreciated!

Comment: I think that scipy uses Cephes for Bessel functions of real values., you can browse the source code in github [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/special/cephes). The Bessel function files, e,g, j0.c, j1,c, jv.c... are profusely commented with the type of information you are after.

Comment: @Jaime that's good stuff - plenty to eat. Thanks! For future reference, if I wanted to look into my computer and find this type of information out by myself, where would I look (or is it too complicated?)

Comment: The C source code doesn't get installed with the package, only compiled binaries do. In any case, you can find out where your scipy got installed following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory),