# python unittest with coverage report on (sub)processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose, nosetests, coverage.py

I'm using `nose` to run my "unittest" tests and have `nose-cov` to include coverage reports.  These all work fine, but part of my tests require running some code as a `multiprocessing.Process`.  The `nose-cov` docs state that it can do `multiprocessing`, but I'm not sure how to get that to work.

I'm just running tests by running `nosetests` and using the following `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
branch = True
parallel = True

[report]
# Regexes for lines to exclude from consideration
exclude_lines =
    # Have to re-enable the standard pragma
    pragma: no cover

    # Don't complain about missing debug-only code:
    def __repr__
    #if self\.debug

    # Don't complain if tests don't hit defensive assertion code:
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError

    # Don't complain if non-runnable code isn't run:
    if 0:
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
    def __main__\(\):

omit =
    mainserver/tests/*
```

### EDIT:

I fixed the `parallel` switch in my ".coveragerc" file. I've also tried adding a `sitecustomize.py` like so in my site-packages directory:

```
import os
import coverage
os.environ['COVERAGE_PROCESS_START']='/sites/metrics_dev/.coveragerc'
coverage.process_startup()
```

I'm pretty sure it's still not working properly, though, because **the "missing" report still shows lines that I know are running (they output to the console)**.  I've also tried adding the environment variable in my test case file and also in the shell before running the test cases.  I also tried explicitly calling the same things in the function that's called by `multiprocessing.Process` to start the new process.

Answer (score 2):

First, the configuration setting you need is `parallel`, not `parallel-mode`.  Second, you probably need to follow the directions in the [Measuring Subprocesses](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/subprocess.html) section of the coverage.py docs.

Comment: The command switch for coverage is `--parallel-mode` so I assumed that's what it was in the config.  Thanks for pointing out that page, I'll see if I can get that working.  And thanks for developing such a great testing tool!

Comment: please see my edit above...  I still can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is if you see more than one coverage file while running coverage. Maybe it's only a matter of combining them afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I only ever got one file.

Comment: Could you pass full command line, I am trying to crack similar problem. However mine seems to be even more complex. If I find anything useful will post it here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember...  It was probably `nosetests --with-coverage`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** — to use `coverage` + `nosetests` + nose’s `--processes` option, set coverage’s `--concurrency` option to `multiprocessing`, preferably in either `.coveragerc` or `setup.cfg` rather than on the command-line (see also: [command line usage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html#execution) and [configuration files](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#run)).

---

*Long version…*

I also fought this for a while, having followed the documentation on [Configuring Python for sub-process coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html) to the letter. Finally, upon re-examining the output of `coverage run --help` a bit more closely, I stumbled across the `--concurrency=multiprocessing` option, which I’d never used before, and which seems to be the missing link. (In hindsight, this makes sense: nose’s `--processing` option uses the `multiprocessing` library under the hood.)

Here is a minimal configuration that works as expected:

---

`unit.py`:

```py
def is_even(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

`test.py`:

```py
import time
from unittest import TestCase

import unit


class TestIsEvenTrue(TestCase):
    def test_is_even_true(self):
        time.sleep(1)  # verify multiprocessing is being used
        self.assertTrue(unit.is_even(2))


# use a separate class to encourage nose to use a separate process for this
class TestIsEvenFalse(TestCase):
    def test_is_even_false(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.assertFalse(unit.is_even(1))
```

---

`setup.cfg`:

```
[nosetests]
processes = 2
verbosity = 2

[coverage:run]
branch = True
concurrency = multiprocessing
parallel = True
source = unit
```

---

`sitecustomize.py` *(note: located in [site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory))*

```py
import os
try:
    import coverage
    os.environ['COVERAGE_PROCESS_START'] = 'setup.cfg'
    coverage.process_startup()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

---

```
$ coverage run $(command -v nosetests)
test_is_even_false (test.TestIsEvenFalse) ... ok
test_is_even_true (test.TestIsEvenTrue) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 1.085s

OK

$ coverage combine && coverage report
Name      Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
-------------------------------------------
unit.py       4      0      2      0   100%
```