# Where does pip install its packages?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I activated a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) which has pip installed. I did

```
pip3 install Django==1.8
```

and Django successfully downloaded. Now, I want to open up the Django folder. Where is the folder located?

Normally it would be in "downloads", but I'm not sure where it would be if I installed it using pip in a virtualenv.

Comment: Can the directory in which to install packages be overridden via CLI args, environment variables or a config file?

Comment: @JohnCarrell yes you can with --target libs e.g. to install to libs/

Comment: LOL. Well, @AndersRuneJensen in the 4 years it took you to answer my question, my Python Fu has improved significantly. I wish I'd remembered I posted this adorable question and come to answer it myself but you beat me to it! Thank you, though, for not answering a very naive question rudely. +1 to you , sir!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

*pip* when used with *virtualenv* will generally install packages in the path `<virtualenv_name>/lib/<python_ver>/site-packages`.

For example, I created a test virtualenv named **venv_test** with *Python* 2.7, and the `django` folder is in `venv_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django`.

Comment: Sometimes you may not know the virtualenv name/path, such as using with Jupyterhub/binderhub spawned resources. I found way #1 [here](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2011/10/python-list-all-packages-installed.html) to work when `pip show` did nothing.  Briefly, it consist of entering the appropriate python console and typing `help("module_name")`, where `module_name` is replaced with the actual module name in which you are interested. You can see the installed modules with `help("modules")` in the python console.

Comment: in which way you built your virtualenv? I am using conda to create my virtual environment while the pip3 didn't install package in the folder you mentioned

Comment: At the time (almost 4 years ago), I was using *virtualenv* and Python 2.x. Now, I am using venv and Python 3.5.x. I still find the same general folder structure, though. With Anaconda, that's a curated, distinct distribution, so it may structure things differently, at least in part.

Comment: Some of the other answer provide more generic ways to locate a package location.

Comment: but if you have two versions of python: 3.8 and 3.7, where does it install it?

Comment: @NathanB type `where pip` to figure out which version it is using. It'll install to the locations specified in the `PATH` variables, which may be the other version actually, because that's how it works.

Answer (score 1167):

`pip show <package name>` will provide the location for Windows and macOS, and I'm guessing any system. :)

For example:

```
> pip show cvxopt
Name: cvxopt
Version: 1.2.0
...
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: On mac this showed me a directory with the awscli source code, but no binary. :/

Comment: Worked on my Mac. Directory had a .py file in it

Comment: Correct, but to be fully compliant with the question asked, it should be `pip3 show <package name>`

Comment: i'm using python 3.6 on windows and "pip" refers to pip for python 3.  i don't need to specify "pip3".

Comment: @CoryKlein Rather than `site-packages/`, I found it in `~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/`

Comment: I ask a more boundary but useful question: if you haven't install any package then how can you know where will pip3 will put the downloaded package?

Comment: Worked very well for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: what about with pip3? pip3 still seems put site-packages in lib/python2.7?

Comment: `pip show pip` works. On the off chance you don't have any packages installed. Default (on Windows) seems to be `%PYTHONHOME%\lib\site-packages`. (In case others are having weird issues installing due to obnoxious corporate firewalls and certificates and every tool on the planet using different cacert bundle locations and formats.)

Comment: Finally found the binary folder for pip (Anaconda via brew). In my case it was in `~/.local/bin/`
I just had to threaten to uninstall it with `pip uninstall`, then it revealed the binary location.

Comment: `pip show ...` may not always give the correct answer. Calling `pip show` with the specific `python` executable is better, e.g. `python -m pip show...` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages/69035259#69035259

Comment: On windows `pip show x` will give you a `.......\local-packages\Python311\site-packages/` which contains python code. For me I found the executables under `.......\Scripts` instead.

Answer (score 216):

`pip list -v` can be used to list packages' install locations, introduced in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31

> Show install locations when list command ran with “-v” option. (#979)

```
>pip list -v
Package                  Version   Location                                                             Installer
------------------------ --------- -------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
alabaster                0.7.12    c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages pip
apipkg                   1.5       c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages pip
argcomplete              1.10.3    c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages pip
astroid                  2.3.3     c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages pip
...
```

---

This feature is introduced in `pip` 10.0.0b1. On [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), `pip` or `pip3` installed with `sudo apt install python-pip` or `sudo apt install python3-pip` is 9.0.1 which doesn't have this feature.

Check https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for suitable ways of upgrading `pip` or `pip3`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: For me, it doesn't show the install location (on Linux Mint 19.3)

Comment: The `pip` installed using `sudo apt install python-pip` or `sudo apt install python3-pip` is 9.0.1. Check https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for suitable ways of upgrading `pip` or `pip3`.

Comment: Calling `pip` directly may not always give the correct answer. Calling `pip` with the specific `python` executable is better, e.g. `python -m pip list -v` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages/69035259#69035259

Comment: Even if you use the `pip` that's a subfolder of the executable, that doesn't necessarily use the same env variables and may just install them to a different location. I have Python installed in 3 locations: Network drive (embedded), local embedded, and local env variable install. PIP just gets confused and puts them in the wrong place...

Answer (score 65):

Easiest way is probably

```
pip3 -V
```

This will show you where your pip is installed and therefore where your packages are located.

Comment: Calling `pip` directly may not always give the correct answer. Calling `pip` with the specific `python` executable is better, e.g. `python -m pip -V` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages/69035259#69035259

Comment: `pip3 -V` fails if package was installed without `sudo`.

Answer (score 29):

The safest way is to call `pip` through the specific `python` that you are executing. If you run `pip show pip` directly, it may be calling a different `pip` than the one that `python` is calling. Examples:

```
$ python -m pip show pip
$ python3 -m pip show pip
$ /usr/bin/python -m pip show pip
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip show pip
```

Here's an example showing how they can differ:

```sh
$ pip show pip

Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

$ python -m pip show pip

Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 27):

In a Python interpreter or script, you can do

```
import site
site.getsitepackages() # List of global package locations
```

and

```
site.getusersitepackages() # String for user-specific package location
```

For locations third-party packages (those not in the core Python distribution) are installed to.

On my [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29)-installed Python on macOS, the former outputs

`['/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`,

which canonicalizes to the same path output by `pip show`, as mentioned in a previous answer:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.getsitepackages

Comment: It seems that all packages do not implement the functions `getsitepackage()` and `getusersitepackages()`. At least those functions do not exist for package `statsmodels`…

Comment: @GaelLorieul There is no such thing. These two functions are part of the `site` module; it does not make sense to talk about packages "implementing" them. These are the default locations for *any* package installed using `pip`, including, in particular, `statsmodels`.

Answer (score 25):

By default, on Linux, Pip installs packages to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

Using virtualenv or --user during install will change this default location. If you use `pip show` make sure you are using the right user or else `pip` may not see the packages you are referencing.

Comment: Linux: Installing packages in `python3` as root - not recommended - will go in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/`. As normal user, they will go in `/home/normaluser/.local/lib..`. I wonder what is `/ root/.local/lib..` for.

Comment: `/root/.local/lib` occurs when you do `sudo pip uninstall --user package`. I.e. it happens when you do a user installation while sudo-ing. Which makes sense since `/root` is the user folder of the root user.

Answer (score 13):

One can import the package then consult its help

```
import statsmodels
help(sm)
```

At the very bottom of the help there is a section `FILE` that indicates where this package was installed.

This solution was tested with at least matplotlib (3.1.2) and statsmodels (0.11.1) (python 3.8.2).

Comment: OMG. I wish I had known about `help()` months ago! I even wrote my own code to dump out the `__doc__`. Now I'm help addicted. I'm doing `help(everything)` 20 times a day. **Help!**

Answer (score 8):

```bash
% python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('purelib'))"
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages
% pip show yt-dlp
Name: yt-dlp
Version: 2023.3.4
Summary: A youtube-dl fork with additional features and patches
Home-page: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp
Author:
Author-email:
License:
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: brotli, certifi, mutagen, pycryptodomex, websockets
Required-by:
```

[How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory/52638888#52638888)

or shorter `python -m pip show pip`

[Where does pip install its packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages/69035259#69035259)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed packages via pip and are running the code on Windows, the package should be located in one of the following directories:

User Site Packages: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\PythonXX\site-packages
Global Site Packages: C:\Program Files\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages
Note that "USERNAME" and "XX" will depend on your system configuration and the version of Python you are using. Also, if you have installed Python in a different location than the default, the paths may differ.

If you're not sure where the package is installed, you can open a command prompt and type pip show 'package-name'. This will show you the installation location of the package.