# How to update a file in a package?

Tags: python, package

I have a python package called `iri2016`, `pip` installed in the anaconda python distribution. The package contains a file with outdated data. How can I replace that file manually with another file but with a similar filename?

Comment: Can you link to the respective file on the iri2016 github project?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  here it is. https://github.com/rilma/pyIRI2016/blob/master/pyiri2016/data   the file in the project GitHub is also outdated. I want to replace the file from other places, like this one http://irimodel.org/indices/

Comment: Hm, the author didn't make the data directory configurable. You're gonna have to fiddle. If you just want to get it working, [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages) where the package is installed and place the data inside it. For a more permanent solution, fork the github repository to your account. Then either add the updated files into the data directory, or modify the code to make the directory configurable. Then [pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) your own package.

Comment: The best solution would be to open a pull-request to make that data directory configurable, but then it depends on whether the author is willing to accept it.   

By the way, Fortran!?!? Wow :)

Comment: Thank you MarkM. I will try this one