# Pip install on windows is giving can not combine '--user' and '--target'

Tags: pip

I am trying to run below commands but it's not working on my windows machine.

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\python-7>pip install chalice -t .
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'

C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\python-7>pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" chalice -t .
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
```

Can someone please let me know if there is any alternative to get the module in the same directory ?

### UPDATE

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\python-7>pip install --target=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\python-7 chalice
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
```

Comment: why are you using `pip install chalice -t`, It is working by simply running `pip install chalice`

Comment: @AhmadAnis I am trying to get the module in the same directory so that I can zip it up along with the code

Comment: Then it would be `pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default chalice`  check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Comment: gives me the same error.

Comment: then just install it using `pip install chalice` and locate it and make its copy and save it to your desired destination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages

Comment: yep. Did that. I was curious to why this is happening. Thanks !

Comment: @Naxi did you figure out what was wrong? Having the same issue here

Answer (score 5):

add `--no-user` at the end of the command and it should work

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

This happens with the Python version distributed on the Windows AppStore.

I believe it's because that version installs the basic executables under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps, a secured location that users cannot modify; pip is then aliased to actually run as something like `pip --user C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.<version>_<id>\LocalCache\local-packages\Python<version>`, so users will install packages to a writeable folder.

Hence, as soon as you try to add `--target`, pip breaks.

Comment: Thanks, Fastest for me, uninstall the Python version distributed on the Windows AppStore, then download and install the version from python.org

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\python-7>pip install chalice