# Broken pip installation only works with sudo

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, sudo

If I try to install something with pip e.g. `python3 -m pip install torch==1.9.1+cu111 --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 69, in _build_session
    if options.cache_dir else None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

This throws the same error: `python3 -m pip install --user torch==1.9.1+cu111 --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`.
Installing with `sudo` does the job but it does not seem right. How can I fix my pip? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
python3 -m pip install --user torch==1.9.1+cu111 --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This would install into your user directory.

**Edit**

The exact location where `pip` installs packages depends on many factors, including whether [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) or third party environment managers (e.g. conda) are used. It is of course OS  and version dependent, too. There are lots of blogs and SO posts dedicated to the subject, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages).

By default, if neither virtual env nor conda are used, reasonably recent python/pip versions on most Linux flavours write to either `/usr/lib[64]` or `/usr/local/lib[64]`, both of which are root-writeable. A possible workaround is to use the `--user` flag, as mentioned above.

Comment: Yes this works. But is the behavior above normal? I don't remember it pip being broken like that

Comment: The details of where pip installs packages strongly depend on the details of your setup, i.e. if you are using virtual environments, some other environment managers (Anaconda, etc) and other stuff. I have experienced this issue myself on a vanilla python installation, so I guess it is pretty normal. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages for a more detailed discussion of where pip installs packages

Comment: With `vanilla python installation` you mean no virtualenv / conda / etc?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: If you want to add that tot he answer that could help in the future other people