# R Tools client: couldn't create connection to server. Launching server using command dotnet failed. Error: spawn dotnet ENOENT

Tags: r, visual-studio

When trying to use the plot function in an R notebook on visual studio, nothing is shown and I obtain the following error:

```
[Error - 6:53:47 PM] R Tools client: couldn't create connection to server.
Launching server using command dotnet failed. Error: spawn dotnet ENOENT
```

These are the loaded libraries:
library(ggplot2)
library(TOSTER)
library(effectsize)
library(lme4)
library(e1071)
library(lmerTest)
library(moments)
library(influence.ME)
library(Rmisc)
library(emmeans)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(psych) # corr.test

Do you know where the problem could come from?

Thank you very much in advance,

Elena

Answer (score 4):

I think that the problem is caused by the instalation of Rtools, that overwrites the configuration of R.

To fix this go to your settings,

Ctrl-Shift-P >>> Preferences: Open keyboard shortcuts, and remove this configration r.executeInTerminal that's the one of Rtools.

Then it should work.

You can read more from this answer [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543130/15059840)

Comment: how to remove it? when i right-click the option to remove is inactive

Comment: Thanks. I just removed R Tools from the vscode Extensions menu where I also installed it from