# How to install pipenv on Windows?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipenv-install

I need to install pipenv on Windows and I use this [tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/install-pipenv-windows/). **However** I get an error. I use **Python 3.9.13** and **pip 22.3**. I installed pipenv with this command *pip install pipenv*, then I have to do this:

[image]

but I didn`t get it. So I passed it  and entered this command *pipenv -h*. Finaly I got this error:

[image]

**Could you help me please?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the `Scripts` directory to PATH environment variable as in the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should locate where pip installed your package.
You can use `pip show pipenv` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages)

For me it was in

```
%APPDATA%\Python\Python311\site-packages
```

So then I added

```
%APPDATA%\Python\Python311\Scripts to the PATH
```

**NOTE**: `%APPDATA%` points to `AppData\Roaming`, not `AppData\Local`.