# There are several packages installed in my virtual environment but pip list doesn't show anything

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

I've created a new Django project since almost 1 month ago. I have several packages installed. As I'm using virtual environment I can find  all these packages in this directory **F:\newEnironment\Lib\site-packages**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g18sg.png)

Now when I activate my environment and go on my project, pip command doesn't do anything. I want to use pip lists and pip freeze. Both returns nothing.

Some of the project abilities won't work if these packages aren't installed. I can successfully run the project on my machine and that's why I'm quite sure this packages are installed. For instance when I write **pip list** in CMD it shows me that **pillow** isn't installed globally on my machine. As you see in the picture above it includes in site-packages directory which means I have it installed locally. Not only that, my projects pictures are works correctly because of **pillow**.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to deal with all issues; we can simply ignore them. I found out that this problem occurs only on this specific **environment**. I perform all my projects inside ***Virtual environment***. All my past projects work well, and for them all pip commands are appliable.

So, I just decided create a new environment and move my projects into it. I managed to run pip commands inside this new environment though, I had to install all my packages again. I've not figured out what could have caused this issue yet.

Comment: Who knows? Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip freeze` instead of `pip list` from within the `venv` to show the full list of installed packages. Also, ensure you always install packages from inside the environment (from both cmd and your IDE)

Comment: As I've explained all pip commands doesn't return anything include pip freeze

Comment: is `pip` recognized as command? are you inside the virtual environment when executing `pip freeze`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm inside virtual environment and when I type pip it returns me all pip commands but none works

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309460/11961036)! It will show the path where a library is installed. Try for example `pip show pillow` from both inside and outside the `venv`

Comment: are you activating your `venv` like so? `.\newEnironment\Scripts\activate`

Comment: Performing this command globally returns me: WARNING: Package(s) not found: whitenoise but in my environment it returns the following text:                            Name: Pillow
Version: 9.5.0
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Author: Jeffrey A. Clark (Alex)
Author-email: aclark@aclark.net
License: HPND
Location: f:\developers\newenironment\lib\site-packages

Comment: @Ramin i see. so basically the library looks installed but when doing `pip freeze` / `pip list` it is not listed. If you need to install `pillow` globally, then you have to launch `pip install` from outside the environment, and then it will be installed in `appdata/local`. I can safely say it's very strange. Try launching the command `pip list -v`. it will show the list of all packages with all the installation paths