# Why does Python site-packages path have different case than Windows path?

Tags: python, windows, path, python-import, enthought

I listed my site-packages path following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) from another question:

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

which returned this result:

```
['C:\\Users\\bbrown\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User',
'C:\\Users\\bbrown\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\bbrown\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata',
 'C:\\Users\\bbrown\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\bbrown\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64',
 'C:\\Users\\bbrown\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Yet (after showing hidden files and folders in my Windows 7 Appearance control panel) it appears that my site packages are exclusively in

`C:\Users\bbrown\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\Lib\site-packages`

`lib` vs. `Lib`. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

That's just how file paths work on Windows. Windows paths are case-insensitive.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why wouldn't the rest of the path be lowercase?

Comment: @TomZych: No clue. I'm just saying why the case mismatch isn't causing problems, not why the case mismatch exists.

Comment: The reason why is a combination of how Windows and Python deal with path strings, very historically contingent. But the key takeaway is that you can never make any assumptions about the case of a path in Windows. If you want to compare two paths, you must always case-normalize them first.

Comment: Doh. I'm so embarassed that I hadn't realized Windows path were case insensitive that I want to delete my question. But won't. Still begs question: How did Python end up capitalizing the directory in its representation?

Comment: The reason is easy to find in the corresponding code: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Lib/site.py#l297: The `lib\site-packages` part is hardcoded - while the remaining part of the paths is taken from the installation/environment.

Comment: @sebastian Good find, you should add that as an answer to the question!  user2357112 appears to be answering a different question ("Are windows paths case-sensitive?")

Comment: @wim: Well, it *used* to be a question about case-sensitivity.