# Install third-party Markdown extension in Pelican

Tags: python-2.7, markdown, pelican

I'm using Pelican for a static blog, and attempting to install the [figure-ref](https://github.com/cmacmackin/figure-ref) extension. Since I'm using Markdown, the plugin relies on the [figureAltCaption](https://github.com/jdittrich/figureAltCaption) third-party Markdown extension. **However I have no idea how to install it**.

Pelican has an `MD_EXTENSIONS` [configuration option](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html?highlight=md_extensions), but I've tried a few obvious options with no luck. It seems like this is a dead-simple gimme but it's not clear how to proceed. Would love some suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the author of figureAltCaption appears to have not provided an install script. My suggestion would be to create one and contribute it as a pull request. This [tutorial](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Tutorial:-Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown) about creating Extensions for Python-Markdown covers creating an install script as well.

However, as a shortcut, you should be able to just copy the `figureAltCaption.py` file to the appropriate directory. Usually you want the site-packages directory. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950101/866026) shows, just do the following from Python:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
```

Then copy the `figureAltCaption.py` file to the first directory returned.

Now that the extension is on your PYTHONPATH, it should be importable. From the Python prompt, try:

```
import figureAltCaption
```

If you get no errors, then it worked and you just need to tell Pelican about it.

```
MD_EXTENSIONS = ['figureAltCaption']
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks so much. I figured it was dead simple. I tried following the directions in the Python-Markdown extensions tutorial but kept running into bizarre errors related to the various fields I had to define in `setup.py.` Thanks!

Comment: This solution also works for MKDocs. Thanks a lot for your contribution.

Comment: Starting with [**3.7.0**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=MD_EXTENSIONS#id2) Pelican version, we need to use [**MARKDOWN setting**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=MARKDOWN#basic-settings) instead of `MD_EXTENSIONS`. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @СашаЧерных, were you able to make this work with pelican 3.7 and up (I'm using v4)? I can't get it to work...

Comment: @haki, this works for me in Pelican 4.0.1. Maybe [**`pelicanconf.py` of my project**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/pelicanconf.py) will help you. Thanks.