# Scrapy-elasticsearch plugin issue

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scrapy

I have recently installed this [plugin](https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch) which is working great ...

Now my issue is that when I repopulate the ES 'index' with new data, I want to delete the existing 'index' first in ES. This is to delete old data in ES.

The above mentioned plugin contains this file *scrapyelasticsearch.py* where I think I can add this code

```
es.delete(index='my-index', doc_type='test')
```

to delete the index before repopulating.

The plugin will automatically recreate the index before inserting data.

**Question: I couldn't find  where this file (*scrapyelasticsearch.py*) is located ?** I am using Ubuntu 16.04, with ES and Scrapy also installed.

I tried this command to find this package

```
dpkg -l scrapyelasticsearch
```

but received this error

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching scrapyelasticsearch
```

If anyone has used this plugin/package, please help me find this file *scrapyelasticsearch.py*

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The file is located in your `site-packages` directory of your python installation. So if you're running on system's python (not a virtual environment) it would be something like:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

**However, you should not modify site-package data!**

What you should do is clone or fork the project on github, make your changes to it, and install this fork on your system.

```
git clone https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch.git
cd scrapy-elasticsearch
your_editing_program 'scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py'
# make changes
pip uninstall scrapy-elasticsearch  # uninstall old original package
pip install .  # install your package, you can also add -e flag for real time modifications
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Granitosaurus [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) helped me ...