# ImportError: No module named <something>

Tags: python, python-import

The following is my directory structure.

```
ankur
├── ankur1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── util.py
├── ankur2
│   └── main.py
└── __init__.py
```

In `main.py`, I am importing the following.

```
import ankur.ankur1.util
```

When I execute the code in Windows, it works perfectly fine. But in Linux, I get the following error.

> ImportError: No module named ankur.ankur1.util

I also read the official python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on Modules and Packages.

Comment: Have you installed the package into the environment?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't get it.  Do we need to install it separately. In my windows env it works fine.

Comment: I believe that it is probably a matter of `PYTHONPATH` issue which is properly configured on windows and not on linux, add the code base to the path, or install it so that it automaticaly locates itself tot he path

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the issue. But how do we configure it to install it automatically. I want users to download the code and run it and not configure the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: create a `setup.py` users will be able to install the package using `python setup.py install` Look into writing a proper setup

Comment: Warning ! The "official python doc on Modules and Packages" mentioned at the end of the question refers to "Python 2". If you want to access python3 doc, click this [official python3 doc on Modules and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your package structure is OK. Your import statement is OK. The only thing missing is for the package to be visible in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), a list of locations where import statements can be resolved.

Usually we do this by "installing" the package locally with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/), which copies your code into [site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638888/674039)<sup>†</sup>. This directory is one of the entries in `sys.path`, so when your code is installed in site-packages, the import statements can now be resolved as usual.

However, to install your code you'll need an installer (`setup.py` script) or a build system (`pyproject.toml` file) defined for the package. Your project doesn't appear to have any installer or build system, so you'll need to create one (see the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) for details about that) and then install the package with `pip`. If you don't want to learn Python packaging just yet, you'll need to find another way around.

It is possible to modify `sys.path` directly in `main.py`, which is subsequently enabling the statement `import ankur.ankur1.util` to be resolved. This is hacky and I recommend against that. It would add the restriction that executing `main.py` is the only entry point to the rest of the package, and so any other code wanting to `import ankur` will first need to know the path to `main.py` on the filesystem. That's a messy approach and should be avoided.

Another way around is to use the environment - there is an environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) which can be used to augment the default search path for module files. In your shell:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent  # linux/macOS
SET PYTHONPATH=C:/path/to/parent   # Windows
```

Where parent is the directory containing `ankur` subdirectory.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>The exact location of site-packages depends on your OS/platform, but you can check with `import sysconfig; sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"]`</sub>

Comment: Why should we not directly modify `sys.path` in code? [This highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/4688119) directly modifies the python path from the program.

Comment: It's messy, generally unnecessary, and it's not scaling well. Each entry in `sys.path` is searched on each import statement. So, if every library installed has decided to insert in `sys.path`, instead of just installing into site-packages dir as usual, then the import system becomes slow and unwieldy. Even a [comment from the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder/4383597#comment53217573_4383597) warns this is not a good solution. Avoid to insert `sys.path` unless you really need a location to be searched first before the site-packages.

Comment: I think when you are in the folder above ankur, type `pip install -e .`. I think this installs your package locally and you dont need any setup tools. In general, maybe it is worth to take a look on relative package imports https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: `export` isn't available on all platforms, so using it is not always a viable workaround.

Comment: @martineau The Windows equivalent is SET

Comment: Environment variables defined via `SET` on Windows are not permanent and disappear when that `cmd` shell exits — so I don't think it's quite equivalent.

Comment: @martineau The same is true of `export`.

Comment: Hello. What would setup.py script look like? I am encountering similar issue as OP.