# Pylint complains about relative import but Python does not accept absolute import

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-import

I have read many previously asked questions about absolute and relative imports but I still cannot figure out how to solve the issue I have.

All my code is in the same directory contrary to some previously answered [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something). I have added an empty `__init__.py` as [suggested in some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) but it also does not change my issue.

My app structure:

```
cli/
    tests/
        __init__.py (empty)
        base.py
        util.py
        main.py
```

In `base.py`, doing `from util import magical_function` works (I can run my tests) but Pylint complains:

```
************* Module tests.base
W: 33, 0: Relative import 'util', should be 'tests.util' (relative-import)
```

I am running my tests using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CURRDIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"

export PYTHONPATH=${CURRDIR}/../

source ${CURRDIR}/../activate
python ${CURRDIR}/../tests/main.py "$@"
```

`activate` starts the virtual environment:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

source ${DIR}/.virtualenv/bin/activate
source ${DIR}/.virtualenv/bin/postactivate
```

Following the instructions and having `from tests.util import magical_function` results in an error when running the tests: `ImportError: No module named util`.

How to change my import to have a working Python code and no errors found by Pylint (without disabling one of its checks)?

Comment: @wim It seems the OP has clearly stated that his question slightly differs from the one you identified as a dupe. Care to explain why he was wrong?

Comment: I've reopened it.  The problem is the same cause, but best practice here would probably be to add a `setup.py` and install the package in development mode, before executing the test suite.  I'm unable to find a good duplicate about that, there are many questions on the topic but they are mostly full of crap answers and bad advice  :-\

Comment: Armand should add details of how the test runner is invoked, and where the library code lives.

Comment: @wim After further testing, the issue is due to the virtual environment (sorry I did not mention that in my initial question). I have added the two scripts used when running the tests.

Comment: That's somewhat messy way to run the tests.  It is also relevant which directory the script lives in, and from which directory you execute that script.  What is the point of `tests/main.py`? Why not just use a proper test runner such as nose or pytest?