# Python can't find module in parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have a folder structure for a Python project as follows:

```
proj/
├── cars
│   ├── honda.py
│   └── volvo.py
├── trucks
│   ├── chevy.py
│   └── ford.py
├── main.py
└── params.py
```

Contents of `params.py`:

```
""" Parameters used by other files. """

serial = '12-411-7843'
```

Contents of `honda.py`:

```
""" Information about Honda car. """

from params import serial

year = 1988
s = serial

print('year is', year)
print('serial is', s)
```

From within the `proj/` folder I can run scripts using iPython:

```
$ cd path/to/proj/
$ ipython

In [1]: run cars/honda.py
year is 1988
serial is 12-411-7843
```

If I try to run the script using the `python` command, I get a module not found error for `params.py`:

```
$ cd path/to/proj/
$ python cars/honda.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cars/honda.py", line 5, in <module>
    from params import serial
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'params'
```

Why doesn't the approach using the `python` command work?

NOTE - The examples above are executed on a Mac using the Anaconda Python distribution. There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something) about an import issue when running on Windows vs Linux machines. However, my question is related to using iPython vs `python` on the Mac to run scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named <something>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something)

Comment: @Dyno I edited my question to explain the difference from the possible duplicate question.

Comment: @wigging does my solution below work for you? If not, can you say why not?

Comment: @wigging Thanks, I totally missed that distinction & the current answers all seemed to be using the same train of thought. Hopefully your edit will help find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Above `from params import serial` insert:

```
import sys
[sys.path.append(i) for i in ['.', '..']]
```

This will add your current working directory and its parent directory to the list of locations from which you can import.

#### Handling imports when running script from a parent directory of `proj`

If you want to be able to import `params` into `cars/honda.py` when running your script from directories that are parents of `project`, you can use the following:

```
import sys
import os
from functools import reduce

# allow imports when running script from within project dir
[sys.path.append(i) for i in ['.', '..']]

# allow imports when running script from project dir parent dirs
l = []
script_path = os.path.split(sys.argv[0])
for i in range(len(script_path)):
  sys.path.append( reduce(os.path.join, script_path[:i+1]) )
```

Comment: This works from within the `proj/` folder. Is there a way to make it work relative to the path of the script that is run?

Comment: @wigging I updated my response to handle the case where you run the script from a parent directory of `proj/` does this help? In general, just use `sys.path.append()` to add to the list of paths from which you can import resources...

Comment: So why is iPython able to find the files but the `python` command requires defining the path?

Comment: @wigging where did you start the ipython server, and did you modify your path before, while, or since using ipython?

Comment: I started the iPython REPL (not Jupyter Notebook) from within the `proj/` folder. With iPython, I did not have to modify the path, everything ran fine.

Comment: @wigging if this is the case after a restart, try printing (sys.path) from both iPython and Python. You should see they're different. Any number of things may have influenced either path -- these details are specific to your setup on your machine. Do be aware that iPython / Jupyter cache imports, so if you modified your path and imported inside iPython, that import may remain available to you even if you remove the path modification code. I hope this helps.

Comment: this is a star-worthy post :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want imports to be referenced of the base `proj` directory you must set the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) to that directory. Currently `honda.py` is looking around for a `moudule` called `params` inside it's own `module`.

```
~$ cd path/to/project
~$ PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
```

Alternatively you could use [`relative imports`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of location,you should write full path for the params.py.
Ipython has a character that can use linux command .so first you cd the directory,the interpreter can find the params.py.
But the command python need full path of the params.py.
So that is the reason you cannot run the processing.