# How to make my program to use my software ( instead of system default software) when switch to another user?

Tags: python, linux, rhel

I am installing a python X module which is dependent on Y software.

There are two versions of Y software available, one that comes with operating system and another I installed it to a custom folder.

When I install "python X" module, I am asking it to take Y from my custom folder as a dependency.

The installation is successful, but while running that "python X" module as a application user then it is always taking Y ( it is making use of the libraries from Y) which is coming with operating system.

If we assume a.py is making use of "python X" module and

if I run

```
python a.py
```

then "python X" module is taking Y from my custom folder, but when I do

```
sudo -u user1 python a.py
```

then "python x" module is taking Y installed from operating system..

Could you let me know how to make "python x" module to always take from my custom folder for whichever user.

Comment: Edit the question to explain what "taking Y" means, especially show the code that does it.

Comment: Thank you for response. Y installs .so files, so "python X" is calling those libraries from Y.

Answer (score 0):

assume "from my custom folder",
you may import "folder.module".

example :

```
#Test3.py
from Sub.Add2 import Add1 as SubAdd1
import Sub.Add2
import Add2

print( 'from Sub.Add2 import Add1 as SubAdd1, call SubAdd1 :' )
SubAdd1()

print( 'import Sub.Add2, call Sub.Add2.Add1(), Sub.Add2.Add2() :' )
Sub.Add2.Add1()
Sub.Add2.Add2()

print( "import Add2, call by 'object'.function name :" )
Add2.Add1()
Add2.Add2()
```

```
#Sub/Add2.py
def Add1():
    print( "Sub.Add2.py : Add1() ", 1 + 1 )

def Add2():
    print( "Sub.Add2.py : Add2() ", 2 + 2 )
```

Add2.py in current folder :

```
#Add2.py
def Add1():
    print( "Add2.py : Add1() ", 1 + 1 + 1 )

def Add2():
    print( "Add2.py : Add2() ", 2 + 2 + 2 )
```

```
> python Test3.py
from Sub.Add2 import Add1 as SubAdd1, call SubAdd1 :
Sub.Add2.py : Add1()  2
import Sub.Add2, call Sub.Add2.Add1(), Sub.Add2.Add2() :
Sub.Add2.py : Add1()  2
Sub.Add2.py : Add2()  4
import Add, call by 'object'.function name :
Add2.py : Add1()  3
Add2.py : Add2()  6
```

Comment: "python X" is a third party pure python package that has .py files but those .py files makes use of software Y which is not python

Comment: You may refer to these : 

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder[/link]
Importing files from different folder

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something[/link]
ImportError: No module named <something>