# When to assume dash m usage and avoid __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

For Python 3.

I just started learning Python. I have PHP and Ruby background.

Currently very confused with modules, `__init__` and `python -m`.

At the moment I have the following:

```
modules/practice.py
tests/test_practice.py
```

In practice.py

```
class First:
  def attempt(self):
    return 'attempted'
```

In test_practice.py

```
from modules.practice import First

class TestMain:
  def test_attempt(self):
    first = First()
    attempted = first.attempt()
    assert attempted is 'attempted'
```

When I run `pytest` I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules`

When I run `python -m pytest` test is green.

However, if I add `__init__.py` files in modules and tests, both are green.

After trying to find out answers on my own I confess I am not sure I am getting it.

Why `pytest` does not work without `__init__`?

When working on a project, when people assume `python -m` will be used and when people add the `__init__.py` files instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add an `__init__.py` file into the `tests` directory.

You should add an `__init__.py` file into the `modules` directory.

Ideally it should be possible to run the test suite with either `pytest` or `python -m pytest`. For this to work, the parent directory of `modules` needs to be present on `sys.path`. Usually you would do this by writing a `setup.py` file for the package and installing your code in "editable" mode. The tests run against the installed code linked in site-packages.

If you don't want to write a `setup.py` file at this stage, you can either export an environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent_of_modules
```

Or you can inject to `sys.path` directly from `conftest.py` file, which gets imported first:

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── practice.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    └── test_practice.py
```

Example:

```
# conftest.py
import os
import sys

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(here))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I am interested in best practices and this is useful. I read somewhere to avoid using PYTHONPATH as in order to not alter how things would work on different environments. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: I agree that PYTHONPATH should not be used in production, but for local development it's fine. It's a convenience. Best practices: write the installer and install your code, with the tests running against the installed package.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476575/674039) for more info.

Comment: Hello! I added the conftest, it seemed the most elegant solution. But what does it do? Why does it work with it, or why does it not work without?

Comment: For `from modules.practice import First` to work, the parent directory of "modules" needs to be present on `sys.path` somehow, and it needs to be there _before_ the file containing that import statement is loaded. Since pytest loads `conftest.py` first, this is an opportunity to modify `sys.path` before loading any test modules.