# Python - unable to figure out how to import a class from a different folder

Tags: python

Bit new to Python, trying to get used to it. Need help importing a class into a file.

Here is my project structure

```
- .venv
- .vscode
- falcon
    - automation
        - project1
            - `__init__.py`
            - plans
                - `__init__.py`
                -  `plan1.py` # from falcon.lib.automation.base import AutomationBase
    - lib
        - automation
            - `__init__.py`
            - ✨ `base.py` # has "class AutomationBase" defined
```

I have a `class AutomationBase` defined in `falcon/lib/automation/base.py` file, and trying to import this into another python file somewhere else - `falcon/automation/project1/plans/plan1.py`

But receiving `No module named 'falcon'` when I try to run `plan1.py` - `python falcon/automation/wps/plans/plan1.py`

Still trying to wrap my head around `__init__.py`, but added in all folders for now. Any ideas how to import `AutomationBase` please. TIA

Comment: Check out these two posts, they might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something

Comment: I ran into `sys.path` in one of links you provided, and was able to fix my issue with this line - `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`. Thank you both