# Relative path ImportError when trying to import a shared module from a subdirectory in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to import a util package one directory up from where my code is, but I get an ImportError which I don't understand.

I have a number of different variations on the import syntax in Python, none of which are working.

There are a number of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none have helped me understand or fix this issue.

Of the top of my head, I have tried the following variations:

```py
import util
import ..util
from .. import util
from ..util import parser
from AdventOfCode2022 import util
from ..AdventOfCode2022 import util
from ...AdventOfCode2022 import util
```

Most of these I guessed wouldn't work, but I tried them anyway to be sure.

Error message:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Directory structure:

```
.
├── day03
│   ├── input.txt
│   ├── part1.py
│   ├── part2.py
│   └── test_input.txt
└── util
    ├── __init__.py
    └── parser.py
```

I just want to import my util package from any "day0*/" directory - not sure why Python makes it so hard!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Which directory or directories do you want to be top-level packages?

Comment: Relative imports are not a directory traversal mechanism. If you ever find yourself thinking "I want to import this thing in this directory", relative imports are not the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't help me. I'm sure it's very accurate and correct, but it's also extremely verbose and difficult to understand and apply to my exact situation. What exactly do I need to type in order for "day03/part1.py" to import "util/parser.py"? Note that the top level directory in the structure I posted, isn't a Python package and that's intentional, I don't need or want it to be one. I just want "day*/*.py" to be able to import "util/*.py" and run without error.

Comment: Create a `__init__.py` file in the parent directory and check again by calling `from AdventOfCode2022.util import <whatever_you_want_to_use_from_util>`

Comment: @Patryk They don't want to make the `AdventOfCode2022` directory into a package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named <something>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476575/674039)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Add the full path to `./util/` to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

For example on Bash, your `~/.bashrc` might have `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/foobar/projects/advent-of-code/util/"`.

2. Add `sys.path.append('/path/to/application/app/folder')` before the import.

The other solutions don't work because:

1. `day03` and the parent directory are not modules with their own `__init__.py`. Lines like `from ..util import parser` only work if everything involved is a module.
2. You are presumably running the code from within `./day03/`.

View this as 'I have a bunch of independent Python projects (`day01`, `day02` etc) that all want to share a common piece of code I have living in a different project (`util`) that lives somewhere else on my computer.'

Comment: It is not the full path to `./util/` that should be added to PYTHONPATH, but the parent directory of that path.

Comment: Is there a functional difference @wim ? Both both work for me.

Comment: There is - for `from util import parser` to work, it's the _parent_ of util that needs to be on `sys.path`.