# Anaconda software can't find packages installed with pip on Windows

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

On Windows, open up Anaconda Prompt and type in the following:

```
pip install json2xml
```

No complaints from `pip` for doing this (replace `json2xml` with your favorite package, I guess). Then, open up Jupyter QTConsole, and try:

```
import json2xml
```

The result is an `ImportError: No module named 'json2xml'`. The package installed (after checking `pip list`), but nothing recognizes it. There is no system `pip` (this is Windows, after all); only Anaconda's `pip` is being used.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure Jupyter is using the same Anaconda Python? Is that the only Python you have installed?

Comment: It should be. I'm able to call up that specific version of `pip` and tell it to install the package, and it will say the package has already been installed, yet nothing can see it. I do have a Python 2.7 environment installed, and I think there's another Python install on my computer somewhere, but I doubt that's what's being called when I use `pip`.

Comment: Hmm..sometimes, you need to use `pip3`, because `pip` might be tied to that 2.7. If `pip3 install json2xml` works, do you get importing success then?

Comment: No, in fact, `pip3` doesn't seem to be a thing; there's only one `pip` that works only for Python 3 (which is the only Python recognized as installed). The `pip3` command works, but it does nothing different; it still says the package is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help, it worked for me.
When you use pip to install a package, by default it will go to your python site-packages.
i. e.

> C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages

From here, you can copy the downloaded packages, then navigate and paste them into your Anaconda site-packages directory.
i. e.

> C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) , you can enter

```
python -m site
```

to print your python package location(s). In my case, I have Anaconda for Windows and do not have a directory C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages but did find my package installed with pip was in C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ . This may be due to adding Anaconda to PATH.