# Pipenv: Command Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I'm attempting to use pipenv. I ran the command `pip install pipenv`, which ran successfully:

```
...
Successfully built pipenv pathlib shutilwhich pythonz-bd virtualenv-clone
Installing collected packages: virtualenv, pathlib, shutilwhich, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, pythonz-bd, virtualenv-clone, pew, first, six, click, pip-tools, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, pipenv
...
```

However, when I run the command `pipenv install` in a fresh root project directory I receive the following message: `-bash: pipenv: command not found`. I suspect that I might need to modify my .bashrc, but I'm unclear about what to add to the file or if modification is even necessary.

Comment: Check `/usr/local/bin/pipenv` — is it there? Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Same problem here: succesfully built pipenv but no sign of pipenv folder in /usr/local/bin .

Comment: Are you installing `pipenv` globally?

Comment: This is a popular question with a lot of highly upvoted answers that recommend the use of `sudo`; however, `sudo` is a _dangerous_ command that should not be run without careful consideration. Please do not blindly copy and paste from the answers here.

Comment: For Windows, 
1. In Gitbash do this and check the location packages.
 pip list -v

and this will give the list of packages and the location the are installed.

2. In command Prompt (cmd)  enter PATH and check in output if the c:\users\test\appdata\roaming\python\python36\Scripts or the path mentioned in output of 1st command is there, if not present update the system Env variable.

3. Close the CMD prompt and GIt Bash and check again, PIPENV should work now.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

That happens because you are not installing it globally (system wide). For it to be available in your `path` you need to install it using `sudo`, like this:

```
$ sudo pip install pipenv
```

Comment: for the copy-and-pasters out there, this command is usually run as `sudo -H pip install -U pipenv` (eg on ubuntu), installing `pipenv` in `/usr/local/bin`. The alternative is a user install, e.g., `$ pip install pipenv`, which is the same as `$ pip install --user pipenv`, which installs things in `$HOME/.local/...`, requiring the `PATH` to be modified as in the other answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111756/127971

Comment: Sudo is dangerous and just not needed for this. Folks should really never run `sudo pip install` anywhere. Most likely you'd want to use your package manager, be it apt, or homebrew, or whatever. For example, `brew install pipenv` works nicely on macOS. If your package manager doesn't happen to have pipenv in its catalog, then `pip install --user` is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: `brew install pipenv` is [discouraged](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#install-pipenv-today) by the maintainers

Answer (score 277):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo -H pip install -U pipenv
```

Comment: @Babbz77 The -H (HOME) for sudo option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default) as specified by the password database.

The -U for pip install upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade - strategy used.

Comment: The same command with pip3 worked for me "sudo -H pip3 install -U pipenv"

Answer (score 134):

If you've done a user installation, you'll need to add the right folder to your `PATH` variable.

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"
```

See [pipenv's installation instructions](http://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv)

Comment: This was useful, in that I needed to run `pipenv run`, and the installation instructions told me so.

Comment: You must test `python3 -m site` to see if the --user-base dir exist!

Comment: This is the right way to rock the local installation. Thank you!

Answer (score 57):

I tried this:

```
python -m pipenv  # for python2

python3 -m pipenv # for python3
```

Why this works: In Bash and other Unix-like shell environments, the `-m` option is used to specify a module to be run as a script.

When you run a Python script using the python -m command, you are telling the Python interpreter to execute the script as if it were a top-level module, rather than as a script file. The `python -m pipenv` command tells the Python interpreter to run the `pipenv` module as a script. The `pipenv` module must be importable from the current working directory or from one of the directories in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me on windows!

Answer (score 33):

I have same problem with `pipenv` on Mac OS X 10.13 High Seirra, another Mac works just fine.  I use Heroku to deploy my Django servers, some in 2.7 and some in 3.6.  So, I need both 2.7 and 3.6.  When HomeBrew install Python, it keeps `python` points to original 2.7, and `python3` points to 3.6.

The problem might due to `$ pip install pipenv`.  I checked /usr/local/bin and pipenv isn't there.  So, I tried a full uninstall:

```
$ pip uninstall pipenv

Cannot uninstall requirement pipenv, not installed
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

$ pip3 uninstall pipenv
Skipping pipenv as it is not installed.
```

Then reinstall and works now:

```
$ pip3 install pipenv
Collecting pipenv
```

Comment: this made it work, many thanks!

Comment: I had to use `pip3 install pipenv` too. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: surprisingly this really worked to get pipenv command to be found on my win11

Answer (score 15):

### Where Python store packages

Before jumping into the command that will install `pipenv`, it is worth understanding where `pip` [installs Python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/399759).

**Global site-packages** is where Python installs packages that will be available to all users and all Python applications on the system. You can check the global site package with the command

```
python -m site
```

For example, on Linux with Python 3.7 the path is usually

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools
```

**User site-packages** is where Python installs packages available only for you. But the packages will still be visible to all Python projects that you create. You can get the path with

```
python -m site --user-base
```

On Linux with Python 3.7 the path is usually

```
~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

#### Using Python 3.x

On most Linux and other Unices, usually Python 2 and Python 3 is installed side-by-side. The default Python 3 executable is almost always `python3`. `pip` may be available as either of the following, depending on your Linux distribution

```
pip3
python3-pip
python36-pip
python3.6-pip
```

## Linux

Avoid using `pip` with `sudo`! Yes, it's the most convenient way to install Python packages and the executable is available at `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`, but it also mean that specific package is always visible for all users, and all Python projects that you create. Instead, use per-user site packages instead with `--user`

```
pip3 install --user pipenv
```

`pipenv` is available at

```
~/.local/bin/pipenv
```

## macOS

On macOS, [Homebrew is the recommended way to install Python](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python#python). You can easily upgrade Python, install multiple versions of Python and switch between versions using Homebrew.

If you are using Homebrew'ed Python, `pip install --user` is disabled. The global site-package is located at

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.y/site-packages
```

and you can safely install Python packages here. Python 3.y also searches for modules in:

```
 /Library/Python/3.y/site-packages
 ~/Library/Python/3.y/lib/python/site-packages
```

## Windows

For legacy reasons, Python is installed in `C:\Python37`. The Python executable is usually named `py.exe`, and you can run `pip` with `py -m pip`.

Global site packages is installed in

```
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages
```

Since you don't usually share your Windows devices, it is also OK to install a package globally

```
py -m pip install pipenv
```

`pipenv` is now available at

```
C:\Python37\Scripts\pipenv.exe
```

I don't recommend install Python packages in Windows with `--user`, because the default user site-package directory is in your Windows roaming profile

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
```

The roaming profile is used in Terminal Services (Remote Desktop, Citrix, etc) and when you log on / off in a corporate environment. Slow login, logoff and reboot in Windows can be caused by a large roaming profile.

Answer (score 9):

1. first install pip using following command

```
   pip3 install pipenv
```

2. Now check whether pipenv is showing by using following command
   `pipenv --version` if you see like `command not found: pipenv` use following commands
3. Now we have to set the path for pipenv, to do that first we have to find the user base binary directory,

## On linux and Mac we can do it as following

```
   python3 -m site --user-base
```

this command will display something like this

```
   /some_directory/Python/3.9
```

use the path displayed in your terminal  and append `/bin` at the end, now your path looks like this

```
   /some_directory/Python/3.9/bin
```

now you have to set the path, if you are using zsh (z shell) type `nano ~/.zshrc` in the terminal or if you are using code editor like VSCode and path is set for VScode  type `code ~/.zshrc`
if you are using bash use `nano ~/.bashrc` or `code ~/.bashrc`

in the file at last add following line

```
    export PATH="$PATH:/somedirectory/Python/3.9/bin"
```

save the file and exit the terminal
now open new terminal and type `pipenv --version` you should see something like `pipenv, version 2022.10.25`

## on Windows we can do as following

```
    python -m site --user-site
```

you should see something like

```
    C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\site-packages`
```

now replace `site-packages` with `Scripts`.
this could return

```
    C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\Scripts
```

You can set your user PATH permanently in the [Control Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/shell/user-environment-variables?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You may need to log out for the PATH changes to take effect.

Answer (score 8):

**OSX GUYS, OVER HERE!!!**

As @charlax answered (for me the best one), you can use a more dynamic command to set PATH, buuut **for mac users this could not work**, sometimes your USER_BASE path got from site is wrong, so you need to find out where your python installation is.

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

you'll get a symlink, then you need to find the source's symlink.

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/python3.6
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71 Mar 14 17:56 /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

(this `../../../` means root)

So you found the python path (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`), then you just need to put in you ~/.bashrc as follows:

`export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin"`

Comment: I installed python3 through Homebrew. When ran `which python3` the output was `/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/python3` which I assigned it to my PATH but still ``pipenv` not found`.  Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what happened, but the following did the work (under mac os catalina)

```
$ brew install pipenv

$ brew update pipenv
```

after doing this i am able to use

```
$ pipenv install [package_name]
```

Comment: It works in mac.

Answer (score 6):

In this case you just need to add the binary path to your bash. In case you're using ZSH for example you need to edit the.zshrc file as an admind and then add the code mentioned by @charlax on the comments above:

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"
```

Answer (score 5):

Installing pipenv globally can have an adverse effect by overwriting the global/system-managed pip installation, thus resulting in import errors when trying to run pip.

You can install pipenv at the user level:

`pip install --user pipenv`

This should install pipenv at a user-level in /home/username/.local so that it does not conflict with the global version of pip. In my case, that still did not work after running the '--user' switch, so I ran the longer 'fix what I screwed up' command once to restore the system managed environment:

`sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall`

^ found here: [Error after upgrading pip: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main)

and then did the following:

`mkdir /home/username/.local` ... if it doesn't already exist

`export PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/username/.local`

Make sure the export took effect (bit me once during this process):

`echo $PYTHONUSERBASE`

Then, I ran the `pip install --user pipenv` and all was well. I could then run pipenv from the CLI and it did not overwrite the global/system-managed pip module. Of course, this is specific to the user so you want to make sure you install pipenv this way while working as the user you wish to use pipenv.

References:

https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/#no-module-named-module-name https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs

Answer (score 5):

OS : Linux 
Pip version : pip3
`sudo -H pip3 install -U pipenv`

OS : Windows
Pip version : any one
`sudo -H pip install -U pipenv`

Answer (score 5):

I'm using zsh on my Mac, what worked for me is at first install pipenv

```
pip3 install --user pipenv
```

Then I changed the PATH in the ~/.zshrc

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

In the editor press *i* to insert your text:

```
export PATH="/Users/yourUser/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"
```

Press *esc* and then write *:wq!*
Close the terminal and re-open it.
And finally write *pipenv*

This way worked for me using macOS BigSur 11.1

Answer (score 5):

#### For thse who installed it using `sudo pip3 install pipenv`, you need to use `python3 -m pipenv shell` or `python3.9 -m pipenv shell`

Answer (score 5):

On Mac you may have to do:

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

Then, `cd` into your root directory to locate the `.zshrc` file.

Then add this to path

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:$PATH
```

Note: 3.9 is the version of Python running on your system.
Note: You can access the `.zshrc` by using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
in your root directory... the file is hidden by default

Save and restart your terminal

Answer (score 4):

HOW TO MAKE PIPENV A BASIC COMMAND

Pipenv with Python3 needs to be run as "$ python -m pipenv [command]" or "$ python3 -m pipenv [command]"; the "python" command at the beginning varies based on how you activate Python in your shell. To fix and set to "$ pipenv [command]": [example in Git Bash]

```
$ cd ~
$ code .bash_profile
```

The first line is necessary as it allows you to access the .bash_profile file. The second line opens .bash_profile in VSCode, so insert your default code editor's command.
At this point you'll want to (in .bash_profile) edit the file, adding this line of code:

```
alias pipenv='python -m pipenv'
```

Then save the file and into Git Bash, enter:

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

You can then use pipenv as a command anywhere, for example:
$ pipenv shell
Will work.

This method of usage will work for creating commands in Git Bash. For example:

```
alias python='winpty python.exe'
```

entered into the .bash_profile and:
$ source .bash_profile
will allow Python to be run as "python".

You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this easily by installing pipenv with my central package manager (apt)

```
sudo apt install pipenv
```

You could easily install pipenv using your package manager (apt, yum, brew) and it adds it directly to your $PATH variables.

More to mention is it works on zsh. I use zsh on Ubuntu and tried adding pipenv to $PATH and other solutions but didn't work till I used apt to install it.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X Catalina it appears to follow the Linux path. Using any of:

```
pip install pipenv
pip3 install pipenv
sudo pip install pipenv
sudo pip3 install pipenv
```

Essentially installs pipenv here:

```
/Users/mike/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv
```

But its not the executable and so is never found. The only thing that worked for me was

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

This seems to result in an `__init__.py` file in the above directory that has contents to correctly expose the `pipenv` command.

and everything started working, when all other posted and commented suggestions on this question failed.

The pipenv package certainly seems quite picky.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on MAC

sudo -H pip3 install pipenv

Comment: this command works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For window users this may be due to conflicting installation with virtualenv. For me it worked when I uninstalled virtualenv and pipenv first, and then install only pipenv.

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
pip uninstall pipenv
pip install pipenv
```

Now `pipenv install xxx` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

After installing pipenv (`sudo pip install pipenv`), I kept getting the "Command Not Found" error when attempting to run the `pipenv shell` command.

I finally fixed it with the following code:

```
pip3 install pipenv
pipenv shell
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I successfully resolved "Pipenv: Command Not Found" on my Mac OSX

1. You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.

   **sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share**
2. make sure that your user has write permission.

   **chmod u+w /usr/local/share**
3. Then Consider installing with Homebrew:

   **brew update** 
   **brew install pyenv**

Answer (score 1):

This simply solved it for me if you are on windows.

```
pip install pipenv
```

Second, replace your `<username>` in the following paths and add them to the PATH environment variable:

```
c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Site-Packages
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts
```

You need to close the Command Prompt and reopen it.
Third, type the following command to check if the pipenv installed correctly:

```
pipenv -h
```

I hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably installed in your user path.

for instance, if your user(username) is tom check this path

**/home/tom/.local/bin/pipenv**

if pipenv exists in the path you can move or copy it to the general user path, so you can execute pipenv from all terminal sessions.

```
cp /home/tom/.local/bin/pipenv /usr/bin/
```

then you should be able to run **pipenv**

Answer (score 0):

You might consider installing `pipenv` via [`pipsi`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi).

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/master/get -pipsi.py | python3
pipsi install pew
pipsi install pipenv
```

Unfortunately there are some issues with macOS + python3 at the time of writing, see [1](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/issues/118), [2](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/issues/100). In my case I had to change the bashprompt to `#!/Users/einselbst/.local/venvs/pipsi/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases of old `pip` version:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install pipenv
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if pipenv is installed:

```
pipenv --version
```

If no version is available on your system, then run the following command to install pipenv

```
sudo aptitude install pipenv
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, what worked on Windows was running Command Prompt as administrator and then installing pipenv globally: python -m pip install pipenv.