# installation of pipenv causes pip3 unusable

Tags: django, linux, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I installed `pipenv` using

`$ pip3 install pipenv` 
which gives me the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`

in order to solve this error I [followed these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/python-pip3-cannot-import-name-main-error-after-upgrading-pip)
 `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall`
now `pip3` command is working on terminal.

now I install `pipenv` using `pip3 install pipenv`

 it installed succesfully but when i tried to execute `pipenv` on termnal it gave me 
 `pipenv: command not found`  
at this point `pip3` also gives `ImportError: cannot import name 'main' error` 
in order to solve this i [followed these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391721/pipenv-command-not-found)

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"
```

at this, point `pipenv` is working but `pip3` is not working .
**How can I make both `pip3` and `pipenv` work at the same time?**

*Also, it seems that I have messed up my pipenv setting now the virtual environment is created by default at `/home/sysadmin`
instead of the location i used to create virtual environment `/home/sysadmin/Desktop/helloworld`*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to overwriting the system-managed version of pip when installing pipenv. You performed the correct first step by getting your system-managed pip back in order:

`sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall`

Once that is done, it is important to note that pipenv will likely not be able to be installed at the global level due to the pip conflict. You can install pipenv at the user level:

`pip install --user pipenv`

This should install pipenv at a user-level in /home/username/.local so that it does not conflict with the global version of pip. In my case, that still did not work after running the '--user' switch, so I ran the longer 'fix what I screwed up' command once more to prep the environment:

`sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall`

and then did the following:

`mkdir /home/username/.local` ... if it doesn't already exist

`export PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/username/.local`

Make sure the export took (bit me once during this process):

`echo $PYTHONUSERBASE`

Then, I ran the `pip install --user pipenv` and all was well. I could then run pipenv from the CLI and it did not overwrite the global/system-managed pip module.  Of course, this is specific to the user so you want to make sure you install pipenv this way while working as the user you wish to use pipenv.

References:

https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/#no-module-named-module-name
https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs

Comment: thanks for the answer but I stopped using pipenv after this problem occurred and currently using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to create my virtual environment. Hope your answer is useful to the next stumbling users.

Comment: since ill be using pipenv for production, wouldnt installing pipenv under a certain user bring me problems later on for the privileges of all that i install on the server?