# Problem with venv when pushing my new lambda function to the cloud by using "amplify push"

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have created an lambda with python which I am now trying to push to the cloud by using "amplify push".

Originally I got two errors, but I solved one by installing pipenv. The second error is:

```
You must have virtualenv installed and available on your PATH as "venv". It can be installed by running "pip3 install venv".
```

But when I am trying to run that command I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement venv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for venv
```

From what I can see I already have virtualenv installed as I can run " py -m venv"

How do I add it to my path as venv? I have tried to do it by creating a Function in Powershell but it didn't work when running "amplify push"

Answer (score 8):

It was solved by reinstalling virtualenv:

1. pip uninstall virtualenv
2. pip install virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to sudo install pipenv.

`sudo -H pip3 install -U pipenv`

[more about this command with pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391721/pipenv-command-not-found)