# Cryptocompare API [ERROR] There is no data for the symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with Python and when I recall the price of all the coins available pretty often I get an error that I cannot filter "[ERROR] There is no data for the symbol XXX"

The code is as follows:

```
import requests
import datetime
import cryptocompare
import datetime
coin_list = cryptocompare.get_coin_list(format=False)
date_today = datetime.datetime.now()
for coin, data in coin_list.items():
        nowprice = cryptocompare.get_historical_price(coin, 'USD', date_today)
        print (nowprice)
```

Why I am getting this error? Is there a way to avoid it? 
And how can I filter the error so it doesn't show on the screen?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @Farhan.K I tried the following: except:
        print ("Exception in user code:")
        print ('-'*60)
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print ('-'*60), but the output is "None"

Comment: You don't need to do that. It should show the traceback itself

Comment: @Farhan.K it doesn't show it, the only output when there is an error is the "[ERROR] There is no data for the symbol $coin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the API you are using (https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/) 
 doesn't have historical information for some of the currencies E.g. https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/nvst/overview. There's nothing you can do about this other than ignore those currencies.

You'll have to edit `cryptocompare.py` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950101/5270506) and change the `query_cryptocompare` function to:

```
def query_cryptocompare(url,errorCheck=True):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url).json()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error getting coin information. %s' % str(e))
        return None
    if errorCheck and 'Response' in response.keys():
        if "There is no data for the symbol" not in response['Message']:
            print('[ERROR] %s' % response['Message'])
        return None
    return response
```