# .exe file created with PyInstaller does not show its GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I wrote a password generator and built a GUI for it using the PyQt5 designer. The script calls the .ui in its initiator and both are in the same folder.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.ui = uic.loadUi('Generator.ui', self)
```

However, after converting both to an .exe file via PyInstaller, after extracting the .exe file from its dist folder and executing it, a console pops up and closes immediately, without showing the GUI.

How can I fix this without manually adding the .ui code to the Generator.py script??

Thank you

Comment: If you run the executable in a command prompt, you can capture the error, then people might be able to assist with a solution. My first guess would be some problem with the path to the .ui file. Do you explicitly include that in your executable?

Comment: You can use the pyuic tool to make the .ui file into a .py file, then subclass the created Ui_whatever class into your GUI class.  This is different than the approach you posted, but I have used this method in many applications created with pyinstaller.

Comment: @Eric how do I include the .ui file in the executable path? I just use 'pyinstaller.exe --onefile Generator.py'

Comment: @MalloyDelacroix I will try this approach as well. So just convert the .ui file into a .py file and then import the generated .py in the main script, which I then convert to the .exe?

Comment: Basically.  In the created .py file there will be a class generated that has the name of whatever you named the widget in QtDesigner.  Import this class and subclass it.

Comment: See the [PyInstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) documentation on adding data files.

Comment: @Eric I added the *GUI.ui* in the pyinstaller call (`pyinstaller.exe --add-data "GUI.ui;GUI.ui" Generator.py`) so there's also a GUI.ui folder in the dist folder with the .exe in it. 

But if I call Generator.exe in the PowerShell, it throws *PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'GUI.ui'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this an answer show I could show an example.  Use the pyuic tool to convert the .ui file to a .py file.  The .py file this creates will have a class in it that is the name of the widget built in Qt Designer.  Import and subclass this class into the GUI class that you are creating.

```
from designer_file import Ui_Gui  # Designer file is the converted .ui file and Ui_Gui is the ui class it created

class GUIWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Gui):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)  # This is necessary to setup the ui when using this method
        # Code here...
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I seem to be stuck somehow. If I try this solution, PyCharm tells me *Unresolved reference 'py'* 
And also, if I import the GUI file, would the *Generator.exe* even work as soon as it is generated, cause the *GUI.py* isn't part of the standard libraries?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Remove the .py from designer_file.py. Yes it should work as soon as it's generated.  Pyinstaller searches the imports in each file and pulls in _almost_ everything thats needed.  It should catch that import fine.

Comment: Now the import worked and I added the rest to the initiator. However, when I run this code in PyCharm, I receive *AttributeError: 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'setup_ui'*

Comment: Sorry, another typo.  self.setupUi(self)

Comment: I moved *Generator.py* and *GUI.py* into a new Folder and ran `pyinstaller.exe -F Generator.py`. It compiles, but when i run the .exe I get a console which closes immediately which has written in it; *This application failed to start, because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem*

Comment: This is the same issue as in this questions [https://stackoverflow.com/q/48007100/6594646](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48007100/6594646).  That user found a temporary solution that worked on their computer.  I have not encountered this error before and am not sure how to completely fix it.

Comment: This link solved the previous error but now I've got the same problem like in the beginning again. The .exe just pops up a command window and closes again

Comment: Seems like there is a problem somewhere else in the code.  As Eric suggested above, if you run it from the command prompt you can see the error.

Comment: The error seems to be in the code. In *Generator.py* I use `self.ui = uic.loadUi('GUI.ui', self)` and later I refer to self.ui for examples for the buttons (`self.ui.buttonGenerate.clicked.connect(self.onGenerate)`). 

How do i solve this reference? if i comment out the load.ui and replace self.ui with `Ui_Generator.buttonGenerate.clicked.connect(self.onGenerate)` it keeps telling me, *'Ui_Generator' has no attribute 'buttonGenerate'* even though it's there, also in the GUI.py

Comment: Since you are subclassing the Ui_Gui class you don't need to declare self.ui.  To access the buttons or any other widget items just use self.  `self.buttonGenerate.clicked.connect(self.onGenerate)`

Comment: So I removed the .ui from every self.ui and commented the out the declaration of self.ui. Now the program runs and if I copy *GUI.ui* and *the platforms folder* (of dist/Generator/PyQt5/Qt/plugins) both *into the Generator) it works.

However it just shows a blank form without any controls visible on it

Comment: solved it, i still had the `uper().__init__(parent)` in it. Now it works, thanks a ton!