# How to robustly retrieve the bin path of a python environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I already figured out how one can retrieve the include and site-package paths of a python environment. For instance the following is [one of multiple possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/):

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib, get_python_inc
print(get_python_lib()) # Prints the location of site-packages
print(get_python_inc()) # Prints the location of the include dir
```

However, I was not able to find a robust method to retrieve the bin folder of a python environment, that is, the folder where python itself and tools like pip, pyinstaller, easy_install, etc., typically reside. Does anyone know how I can get this path from within python?

Some may want to suggest `binpath = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`. On Mac however, this does not work if python was installed as a Framework (`binpath` would point at: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS`)

What could I use instead that works cross-platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stdlib way to get this location is via [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html) module. Works on 2.7 and 3.3+. Works whether or not you are using a virtual environment.

```
>>> from sysconfig import get_path
>>> get_path('scripts')
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin'
```

Almost any package with scripts to install will put them there. However, note that with an imperative installer the `setup.py` code is actually executed, which means it could literally lay down scripts anywhere on the filesystem, given permission.

Comment: Nice, this works! I was just about to object regarding the availability of pip, but you already answered this as well. Thx!

Comment: Note that this works only for pip versions lower than 10.0! :(

Comment: @normanius  The path changed (now in `pip._internal.locations`)