# What's the difference between pip3 and pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I know that `pip3` refers to `python3` and `pip` refers to `python2`. 
When I use `anaconda` environment and set the `python` version as `3.5`, I install a package names `itchat` as following.

```
pip3 install itchat
```

The installation goes on successfully without any errors.

**But** when I type the following commands, strange things happen.
[image]

**But** if I just use `pip install itchat` and type `python` instead of `python3`, things go on as I think.
[image]

I am wondering what leads to this result. 
Why there is the difference between `python` and `python3`?

Thanks for providing your answers!

Comment: had a similar issue using django packages. running pip3 as root solved it to me. I still have no idea what caused it.

Comment: They may both be Python 3.5.5, but do they refer to the same binary? Maybe you have `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`, for example, and each points to a different infrastructure.

Comment: type `which python` and `which python3`

Comment: Compare output of `which python` and `which python3`

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @TomBombadil most probably you have different `PATH` env vars when running `pip3` and `sudo pip3`. Run `echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` and check what's different.

Comment: @DeepSpace @chepner They are the same `PATH`, I think. For `which python`: `/anaconda3/envs/myPy3.5/bin/python` For `which python3`: `/anaconda3/envs/myPy3.5/bin/python3`

Comment: I don't see you using conda environment. Create an environment, activate and then install the package.

Comment: @jalazbe Aug Yes, I finally created the conda python environment and solved this problem.

Comment: @Boooooooooms I wrote the solution. Could you mark it as resolved?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I don't see you using conda environment.

Create an environment

```
conda create -n myenv
```

activate the envinronment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

and then install the package

```
conda install itchat
```

or

```
pip install itchat
```

Comment: I understand it solves the problem. But it doesn't answer the question. `Why there is the difference between python and python3`

Comment: this link can be helpful if above answers are not understood https://www.pythonpool.com/pip-vs-pip3/