# inconsistent python package installation location with prefix

Tags: python, setup.py

I am installing python package with prefix, and getting a following error.

```
$ python3 setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/some_prefix
running install

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /home/user/some_prefix/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''
```

Surely i can `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/some_prefix/lib64/python3.4/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`. But given that the path has python version, I found a fancy way from [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

```
$ python3 -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sc; print(sc.get_python_lib(prefix=\"$HOME/some_prefix\"));"
/home/user/some_prefix/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Unfortunately, they mismatch on `lib` part, apart from negligible trailing `/`. So it still fails.

```
$ python3 setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/some_prefix
running install

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /home/user/some_prefix/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    '/home/user/some_prefix/lib/python3.4/site-packages'
```

Now, how can I properly match it?

I checked the documentation, but I don't think there is a relevant arguments.

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.sysconfig
distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib([plat_specific[, standard_lib[, prefix]]])¶

```
$ python3 -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sc; print(sc.get_python_lib(\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"));"
C/lib64/python3.4
```

Also, which one is right? is lib or lib64? I see more packages in `/usr/lib`.

```
$ ll /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ | wc
     70     554    5408
$ ll /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/ | wc
     11      82     764
```

I am using standard python comes from centos 7.

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.8
```

Comment: So why not use `/home/user/some_prefix/bin/python3` instead to install your package? You are using the wrong Python binary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora / CentOS [patches various Python module](https://src.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/python3.git/plain/00102-lib64.patch) to alter the installation locations, see [this ServerFault post on the difference between `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`](https://serverfault.com/questions/60619/fedora-usr-lib-vs-usr-lib64).

Note that the `/usr/lib64` path is only used for *platform specific code*, not for pure-python libraries. So the correct method to use is to set the [`plat_specific` argument to `get_python_lib()`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib) (the first one) to `True`:

```
$ python3 -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sc; print(sc.get_python_lib(True, prefix=\"$HOME/some_prefix\"))"
```

However, if your target prefix directory is for a *separate Python installation without the Fedora / CentOS patches*, then you should really use the Python binary *installed in that prefix* to handle the installation:

```
$HOME/some_prefix/bin/python3 setup.py install
```

It'll come with all the right system configuration, including an unpatched `distutils` and a `sysconfig` module with the right local `$PREFIX` value, and no `PYTHONPATH` warning will be issued.

And if you wanted to isolate packages from the system installation, use a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and install with the environment-specific Python binary:

```
$ virtualenv name_of_virtualenv_directory
$ name_of_virtualenv_directory/bin/python setup.py install
```